# Cant produce-to OR consume-from kafka broker running inside a container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

### Setting Up

I am using the **[confluent/kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluent/kafka/)** images from docker hub to start the ***zookeeper*** and the ***kafka*** instances in two separate containers. The commands I have used to start the containers are as follows:

```
docker run --rm --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 confluent/zookeeper
docker run --rm --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper:zookeeper confluent/kafka
```

And I have two containers **zookeeper** and **kafka** running now.

> Note that I have mapped ports ***2181*** and ***9092*** of the containers to my host machine ports. I verified that this mapping is working by just trying **localhost:2181/9092** in my browser and I get some errors printed in my running containers' terminals.

Then I created topic by issuing the following command in my **host machine**:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

This is successful and I verified it by listing the topics with the following command:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

---

### Now the ISSUE:

I am trying to produce some messages to the broker with the following command:

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

*I am getting the following exception:*

```
[2017-03-02 20:36:02,376] WARN Failed to send producer request with correlation id 2 to broker 0 with data for partitions [test,0] (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncProducer.scala:103)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:103)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:103)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:101)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.kafka$producer$async$DefaultEventHandler$$send(DefaultEventHandler.scala:255)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$dispatchSerializedData$2.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:106)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$dispatchSerializedData$2.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:100)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:778)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:777)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.dispatchSerializedData(DefaultEventHandler.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:105)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:88)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:68)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:594)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:67)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:45)
```

I read some threads on the internet that suggested that I update my **hosts** file. If so what entry do I have to put in my **hosts** file??

Also some threads suggested I set the ***ADVERTISED_HOST*** entry to correct IP in the **configuration** file. Which *configuration* file??? Where do I make the update?

If it's the **server.properties** file used for the kafka broker then I did try going into the container created by the **confluent/kafka** image. It looks like this:

```
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
delete.topic.enable=true
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.retention.hours=168
num.io.threads=8
broker.id=0
log4j.opts=-Dlog4j.configuration\=file\:/etc/kafka/log4j.properties
log.dirs=/var/lib/kafka
auto.create.topics.enable=true
num.network.threads=3
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
num.partitions=1
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper\:2181
```

Any suggestions how I can overcome this and resolve producing and consuming from the kafka containers possible from my host machine??

Thanks Alot!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to Kafka running in Docker from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker-from-local-machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out within seconds of posting this question.

I had to get the **HOSTNAME** of the container in which the broker was running by issuing:

```
echo $HOSTNAME
```

And I updated my **/etc/hosts** file in my host machine with the *loopback* entry:

```
127.0.0.1     KAFKA_CONTAINER_HOSTNAME
127.0.0.1     ZOOKEEPER_CONTAINER_HOSTNAME
```

Had to do the same with the **zookeeper** container in order for the consumer also to work without an issue.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Note: this is a hack and shouldn't be done. Refer https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/  Zookeeper didn't need to be added anyway

Comment: Post an answer based on the blog post and I can accept it as the answer

Comment: I linked to a duplicate post that has all the necessary information.