# Kafka docker and LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I use the following Kafka Docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/

I'm able to start Apache Kafka with the following properties:

```
<KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>${local.ip}</KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>
<KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT>${kafka.port}/KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT>     
<KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>zookeeper:2181</KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>   
<KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES>15000000</KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES>
```

but I see the following warning when trying to send the message into the topic:

```
WARN 9248 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4 : {post.sent=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
```

I saw a few articles on the internet that told that this issue can be related to old properties like `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` and `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT` and I should reconfigure to `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` and `KAFKA_LISTENERS`. But when I start the Kafka container with the following properties:

```
<KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS>PLAINTEXT://${local.ip}:${kafka.port}</KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS>
<KAFKA_LISTENERS>PLAINTEXT://${local.ip}:${kafka.port}</KAFKA_LISTENERS>                            
<KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>zookeeper:2181</KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>   
<KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES>15000000</KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES>
```

my application unable to connect to Kafka:

```
2018-08-25 16:20:57.407  INFO 17440 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 1.1.0
2018-08-25 16:20:57.408  INFO 17440 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : fdcf75ea326b8e07
2018-08-25 16:20:58.513  WARN 17440 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2018-08-25 16:20:59.567  WARN 17440 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

How to properly reconfigure the Docker Kafka in order to be able to use `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` and `KAFKA_LISTENERS`?

Comment: Where are you using XML to assign things?

Comment: I use io.fabric8 docker-maven-plugin

Comment: Ah, and `local.ip` is being assigned as what by Maven? Because I know if you set the container hostname as kafka, for example, and use `PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092` then it'll at least connect externally after you forward a port

Comment: See if my answer here helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/51634499/2308683

Answer (score 0):

From this awesome [post](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/), here's a good explanation about these properties:

> **LISTENERS are what interfaces Kafka binds to. ADVERTISED_LISTENERS are how clients can connect.**

When your application connects to **one of the addresses from LISTENERS** the Kafka **returns the correspondent KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENER** to that LISTENER you choosed. The KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENER returned is the **address that your application you will really use to communicate with Kafka.**

So, you have to **use in your application** what you set on **LISTENERS Kafka property for PLAINTEXT**.

Using this configuration as you put:

```
<KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS>PLAINTEXT://${local.ip}:${kafka.port}</KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS>
<KAFKA_LISTENERS>PLAINTEXT://${local.ip}:${kafka.port}</KAFKA_LISTENERS>
```

You have to use on your application:

As you used on Kafka docker **${local.ip}:${kafka.port}** you have to get the **assigned kafka docker container IP and use it in your application**.

Just to fill the variables for this scenario, let's suppose your kafka docker container IP 192.250.0.1 and the kafka port used is 9092, **so your application bootstrap.servers property would be: 192.250.0.1:9092**

Here's a command to see what Kafka returns to you when you try to connect using one of kafka's listener:

$ kafkacat -b 192.250.0.1:9092 -L

[kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat) is a very useful tool for test and debug kafka.