# Docker Kafka w/ Python consumer

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-consumer-api

I am using dockerized Kafka and written one Kafka consumer program. It works perfectly when I run Kafka in docker and application at my local machine. But when I configured the local application in docker I am facing issues. The issue may be due to a topic not created until time application started.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  parse-engine:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - "kafka"
    command: python parse-engine.py
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
```

parse-engine.py

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json

try:
    print('Welcome to parse engine')
    consumer = KafkaConsumer('test', bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
    for message in consumer:
        print(message)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    # Logs the error appropriately. 
    pass
```

Error log

```
kafka_1         | [2018-09-21 06:27:17,400] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Started processors for 1 acceptors (kafka.network.SocketServer)
kafka_1         | [2018-09-21 06:27:17,404] INFO Kafka version : 2.0.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
kafka_1         | [2018-09-21 06:27:17,404] INFO Kafka commitId : 3402a8361b734732 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
kafka_1         | [2018-09-21 06:27:17,431] INFO [KafkaServer id=1001] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
**parse-engine_1  | Welcome to parse engine
parse-engine_1  | NoBrokersAvailable 
parseengine_parse-engine_1 exited with code 0**
kafka_1         | creating topics: test:1:1
```

As I already added **depends_on** property in docker-compose but before starting topic application connecting so error occurred.

I read that I can possible to add the script in the docker-compose file but I am looking for some easy way.

Thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to Kafka running in Docker from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker-from-local-machine)

Comment: No, it's different. I am able to connect Kafka but facing an issue like lazy topic creation.

Comment: It's definitely the same. `NoBrokersAvailable` because you're connecting to the wrong bootstrap servers

Comment: Still facing issues so didn't marked as accepted

Comment: Please update your question with your current code, then, because as mentioned, `localhost:9092` in the Python code wouldn't be correct

Answer (score 100):

Your problem is the networking. In your Kafka config you're setting

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
```

but this means that any client (including your python app) will connect to the broker, and then be told by the broker to use `localhost` for any connections. Since localhost from your client machine (e.g. your python container) is not where the broker is, requests will fail.

You can read more about fixing problems with your Kafka listeners in detail here

- [Kafka Listeners - Explained](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/)
- [My Python/Java/Spring/Go/Whatever Client Won’t Connect to My Apache Kafka Cluster in Docker/AWS/My Brother’s Laptop. Please Help!](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/)

So to fix your issue, you can do one of two things:

1. Simply change your compose to use the *internal* hostname for Kafka (`KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka`). This means any clients *within* the docker network will be able to access it fine, but **no external clients** will be able to (e.g. from your host machine):

   ```
    version: '3'
    services:
    zookeeper:
        image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
        ports:
        - "2181:2181"
    kafka:
        image: wurstmeister/kafka
        ports:
        - "9092:9092"
        environment:
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
        KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    parse-engine:
        build: .
        depends_on:
        - "kafka"
        command: python parse-engine.py
        ports:
        - "5000:5000"
   ```

   Your clients would then access the broker at kafka:9092, so your python app would change to

   ```
    consumer = KafkaConsumer('test', bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092')
   ```
2. *Add* a new listener to Kafka. This enables it to be accessed both internally and externally to the docker network. Port 29092 would be for access *external* to the docker network (e.g. from your host), and 9092 for *internal* access.

   You would still need to change your python program to access Kafka at the correct address. In this case since it's *internal* to the Docker network, you'd use:

   ```
    consumer = KafkaConsumer('test', bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092')
   ```

   Since I'm not familiar with the `wurstmeister` images, this docker-compose is based on the Confluent images which I do know:

   (editor has mangled my yaml, you can find [it here](https://gist.github.com/rmoff/fb7c39cc189fc6082a5fbd390ec92b3d))

   ```
    ---
    version: '2'
    services:
      zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
        environment:
          ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
          ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

      kafka:
        # "`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-
        # An important note about accessing Kafka from clients on other machines: 
        # -----------------------------------------------------------------------
        #
        # The config used here exposes port 29092 for _external_ connections to the broker
        # i.e. those from _outside_ the docker network. This could be from the host machine
        # running docker, or maybe further afield if you've got a more complicated setup. 
        # If the latter is true, you will need to change the value 'localhost' in 
        # KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS to one that is resolvable to the docker host from those 
        # remote clients
        #
        # For connections _internal_ to the docker network, such as from other services
        # and components, use kafka:9092.
        #
        # See https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/ for details
        # "`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-'"`-._,-
        #
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
        ports:
          - 29092:29092
        environment:
          KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
          KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
          KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
          KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
          KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
   ```

---

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent*

Comment: getting error after trying first solution "KafkaUnavailableError: All servers failed to process request: [('kafka', 9092, <AddressFamily.AF_UNSPEC: 0>)]" in application

Comment: The yaml provided in the link : https://gist.github.com/rmoff/fb7c39cc189fc6082a5fbd390ec92b3d has a typo and did not work for me

Comment: @joe what's the typo? If you let me know I will update the gist

Comment: In https://gist.github.com/rmoff/fb7c39cc189fc6082a5fbd390ec92b3d#file-docker-compose-yml-L36 , 9092 and 29092 should be inverted:         KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092

Comment: No, that's not correct. `kafka:29092` is how you reference is for hosts on the Docker network. `localhost:9092` is for clients connecting on the Docker host machine, which is why `9092` is exposed in the `ports` statement. Maybe start a new question with details of the problem that you're having using it?

Comment: But in your answer, you've written: "Port 29092 would be for access external to the docker network"

Comment: Anyway, I should've mentioned that it worked after I switched 9092 and 29092

Comment: Ah right, I see the confusion now. My gist has yaml different from the answer. I'll fix this now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to rather use the linux hostname (i.e. the value of `$(hostname)` in bash) of the docker host instead of `localhost` to also enable clients from other machines than the docker host? (as indicated in your references blogpost)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt If I am accessing the kafka server from a different network, would I have to change "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: PLAINTEXT://ipaddress:9092, BROKER://127.0.0.1:9092" ? That way the external app would be redirected to the server ip address?

Comment: And why kafka is pain, when making deployments and services in k8s? When I'm following the same structure...

Comment: If you're on a mac and running into `Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.`, replace `localhost` with `host.docker.internal`. Now `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` should look like `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS:PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://host.docker.internal:29092`

Note that if you're connecting to kafka from another container, you'll need to replace `localhost` in the client's bootstrap servers with `host.docker.internal` as well.

Comment: "My Python/Java/Spring/Go/Whatever Client Won’t Connect to My Apache Kafka Cluster in Docker/AWS/My Brother’s Laptop. Please Help!" The following article is much better than the other one. THANK YOU!

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe there has been some update to the Kafka + Docker configuration. It could be that the Bitnami packaged Kafka environment variables are different. The relevant variables, using Bitnami are `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` and `KAFKA_LISTENERS`. (Actually, for **Bitnami** only, a recent update changed these to be `KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS` and `KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`.) Please leave a comment if you know differently. However for anyone trying to use `KAFKA_HOST_NAMES` and finding this doesn't work, try this intead.

Answer (score 7):

This line

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
```

Says the broker is advertising itself as being available only on `localhost`, which means all Kafka clients would only get back itself, not the actual list of real broker addresses. This would be fine if your clients are only located on your host - requests always go to localhost, which is *forwarded to the container*.

But, for apps in other containers, they need to point at the Kafka container, so it should say `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka`, where `kafka` here is the name of the Docker Compose Service. Then clients in other containers would try to connect to that one

---

That being said, then, this line

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('test', bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
```

You are pointing the Python container *at itself*, not the `kafka` container.

It should say `kafka:9092` instead

Comment: If I am accessing the kafka server from a different network, would I have to change "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: PLAINTEXT://ipaddress:9092, BROKER://127.0.0.1:9092" ? That way the external app would be redirected to the server ip address?

Comment: @Danielle That's correct, except not using the hostname config, but advertised listeners if you're advertising multiple addresses

Comment: @OneCricketeer, what do you mean with "...not using the hostname config, but advertised listeners..."? Do you mean we should use IP address instead of hostname?

Comment: Ah, okay... I think you meant that Danielle should've used 'KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS' instead of 'KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME' here since the values he's using include not just the hostnames, but also the port numbers.

Comment: @IwanSatria That is correct - IMO, always use advertised listeners. Worth mentioning that the advertised host name (and port) properties themselves are deprecated in favor of the `advertised.listeners` broker config

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to access the Kafka Container from an external python client running locally (as a producer) and here is the combination of containers and python code that worked for me (Platform MAC OS and docker version 2.4.0):

zookeeper container:

```
docker run -d \
-p 2181:2181 \
--name=zookeeper \
-e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 \
confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.3
```

kafka container:

```
docker run -d \ 
-p 29092:29092 \ 
-p 9092:9092 \ 
--name=kafka \ 
-e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=host.docker.internal:2181 \ 
-e KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=BROKER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT \ 
-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,BROKER://localhost:9092 \ 
-e KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=BROKER \ 
-e KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1 \ 
-e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \ 
-e KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS="test:1:1" \ 
confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.2.3
```

python client:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:29092'],
value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'),
security_protocol='PLAINTEXT')
acc_ini = 523416
print("Sending message")
producer.send('test', {'model_id': '1','acc':str(acc_ini), 'content':'test'})
producer.flush()
```

Comment: `host.docker.internal` is incorrect as you should be using a `--network` and connecting to `zookeeper:2181` (which is what using a Compose file would do). Also, Confluent images don't use `KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS` env-var, and your internal listener should really be `PLAINTEXT` to be accurately configured inside the docker network

Comment: Plus, this doesn't answer the actual question about the Python client in the Docker container

Comment: Thanks for your comments @OneCricketeer. Sure your suggestions also work but mine worked too, at least for my purpose, which was connecting an external python consumer with a Kafka container. I explained that the first thing before posting the code...
Since I ended at this thread looking for solutions to my problem (external python consumer), I thought that there might be other people with my same problem ending also here. If you find any other thread where this comment is more appropriate, let me know. I did not find it.

Comment: I frequently close posts for this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker Client language doesn't matter. There's many blogs on it, too. https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Answer (score 0):

In my local setup, I had the same issue where all the containers were working fine inside the docker but the connectors were unable to connect to the Kafka.

My Kafka configuration inside `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.0.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
```

Based on google responses I tried `localhost:port`, `127.0.0.1:port`, and `0.0.0.0:port` as the URL in my connector config but nothing worked.

Eventually, I had to pass the actual IP address of my local system and it worked.
I'm using Docker on Windows 10.

ActiveMQ Connector congif:

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.activemq.ActiveMQSourceConnector",
  "activemq.url": "tcp://<my-system-ip>:61616", <-- my system's IP address
  "max.poll.duration": "60000",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "batch.size": "1",
  "name": "activemq-jms-connector",
  "jms.destination.name": "jms-test",
  "kafka.topic": "topic-1",
  "activemq.password": "password",
  "jms.destination.type": "topic",
  "use.permissive.schema": "false",
  "activemq.username": "username"
}
```

I hope this will help anyone struggling with the `Kafka-connect` setup on Windows and Docker.