# why kafka producer is showing me error kafka.conn:DNS lookup failed for <container id>:9092?

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka

I expose the port 9092 then i run the kafka broker inside docker.
But When I run the python script i get the errors

```
ERROR:kafka.conn:DNS lookup failed for b5c5b06f6761:9092 (AddressFamily.AF_UNSPEC)
```

I tried docker ip and machine ip instead of localhost but gives same error.

Here is my code.

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                         value_serializer=lambda x:
                         dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

producer.send('vtintel', value={'id':123})
```

Comment: what's the command you used for starting the docker image?

Comment: i suspect you need to add something in your hosts file (if you use windows)

Comment: docker run -p 8081-8110:8081-8110 -p 8200:8200 -p 9095:9095 -p 9097:9097 -p 9999:9999 -p 9092:9092 -d --name imply imply/imply

Comment: I am using linux

Comment: @Gremi64 That's a hack, please never do that and just fix the actual problem... https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: `imply/imply` doesn't start Kafka, according to docs

Comment: @cricket_007 i know, and you are right to point it out. I thought (don't know why) that he was doing this as a "local test"

Comment: you'll find your answer in @cricket_007 link, or in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52438822/docker-kafka-w-python-consumer/52440056#52440056 or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker-from-local-machine

Answer (score 8):

Same issue with bitnami/kafka. But then I realized that I need to enable accessing Kafka with external clients in docker-commpose.yml. For more info see https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka/ 'Accessing Kafka with internal and external clients' part.

```
To do so, add the following environment variables to your docker-compose:

    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
+     - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
+     - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:29092
+     - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092

And expose the extra port:

    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
+     - '29092:29092'


and access it by 'localhost:29092' not 'localhost:9092' in your python-kafka code.
```

Incase it's not obvious, that should be added to the kafka container (not the zookeeper container)

Answer (score 2):

Docker only handles DNS within its own network, not from your host

You need to Kafka to [advertise itself externally (on localhost)](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/), which is different than just a port forward

And as far as I can tell `-p 9092:9092` is not a port even exposed by the container image you're using

Answer (score 2):

Though it's a late reply it might help anyone later. I have the same problem as you were facing I was using dockerized implementation of edX. 
So to fix that issue just add the following lines in 
         
`/etc/hosts` 
file of your docker container.
first your IP Address then the thing for which the lookup is being failed.
for example in your case lookup is being failed for `b5c5b06f6761` so:

```
173.16.18.22     b5c5b06f6761
```

Note: Here I am using dummy IP address.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem earlier with latest kafka versions. Try mentioning the local address as '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost'. this might help.