# Unable to consume messages from kafka topic (using Python) even after making successful connections and getting messages in a kafka consumer console

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, debezium

I have a setup of Debezium which uses Kafka. I am able to consume messages from kafka console as described in the doc. However, when I create a kafka consumer using Python on my local, I am unable to consume messages. It should be noted that kafka console works just fine!

I tried looking into this issue but was unable to have similar environments/situations

My python code to connect is:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('dbserver1.inventory.customers', group_id='my-group', bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'], auto_offset_reset='earliest')
for message in consumer:
    print(message)
```

This just goes blank regardless of existing messages or new messages pushed to this topic.

I am sure that the messages exist because when I open up a console consumer, I get to see the messages.

Just to be clear on the whole setup:
I have followed this (https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/tutorial#using-mongodb) doc for each step(except the last one).
Everything works but my Python code. 
I also tried creating a consumer with `kafka:9092` bootstrap server but it ends up in an error:

```
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

My local is Mac OS.

FYI:
I am able to get everything else, like topics:

```
>>> consumer = KafkaConsumer('dbserver1.inventory.customers', group_id='my-group', bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'], auto_offset_reset='earliest')
>>> consumer.topics()
{'my_connect_offsets', 'my_connect_configs', 'dbserver1.inventory.orders', 'connect-status', 'dbserver1.inventory.customers', 'dbserver1.inventory.products'}
```

I am starting consumer via command:

```
docker-compose -f debezium-mongodb.yaml exec kafka /kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh \
    --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 \
    --from-beginning \
    --property print.key=true \
    --topic dbserver1.inventory.customers
```

Comment: Can you please post your console consumer using which you can consumer messages successfully.

Comment: @GokulPotluri, done!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your compose file, `localhost:9092` likely will not work in your Python code based on your docker command

1. If your Python code is not running in a container, it needs to read from a different port. If it is running in a container, you must use `kafka:9092`
2. The port you use depends on the advertised listeners of the container

[Connect to Kafka running in Docker from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker-from-local-machine)

Comment: How come new topics gets listed when the broker is `localhost:9092`? As for the docker file: https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/tutorial#using-mongodb

Comment: The topic list comes from Zookeeper and does not use the Consumer API protocol. I have not used the `debezium/kafka` images, so I do not know how their networking is configured, but your Compose file isn't setting the advertised host to be anything external to the docker network https://github.com/debezium/docker-images/tree/master/kafka/0.10#advertised_host_name  I will bet you that if you put your Python code in a container, then use `kafka:9092` as the connection string, it'll likely start working.

Comment: Otherwise, you're welcome to read this blog for more details than are worth explaining again here https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Note: you do not need a `debezium/kafka` image at all... You can swap that out for any other Kafka image.

Comment: I read https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/ and configured my `yaml` file as shown here(https://pastebin.com/SeDZ4aiG)
I am getting an error: https://pastebin.com/6w5CTwGs

Could you see the yaml file and correct me if my configs are wrong?

Comment: You need two listeners. And it doesn't have to be "Fred" :) You only have one, that now says `localhost`, which mean that Debezium won't be able to reach `kafka:9092` anymore. You need one listen internal to the Docker network like `DOCKER://kafka:9092`, then another like `DOCKER_HOST://localhost:29092`, then you use different ports just because Kafka can't advertise two listeners on the same port. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51634499/2308683