# Read Docker Kafka messages populated by debezium postgres connect

Tags: postgresql, docker, apache-kafka, debezium

I am using the Debezium Postgres connector. I have two tables in Postgres named 'publications' and 'comments'. kafka and zookeeper are running in docker containers as per the standard examples.  The postgres is running locally. After using the debezium postgres connect, I have the following topics :

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

- __consumer_offsets
- dbserver1.public.comments
- dbserver1.public.publications
- my_connect_configs
- my_connect_offsets
- my_connect_statuses

I would like to see a list of messages in the topic:

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --topic dbserver1.public.publications
```

> [2019-06-03 21:55:16,180] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=console-consumer-5221] Connection to node -1
>   (kafka/23.202.231.166:9092) could not be established. Broker may not
>   be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2019-06-03
>   21:55:16,289] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=console-consumer-5221] Connection to node -1
>   (kafka/23.202.231.166:9092) could not be established. Broker may not
>   be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2019-06-03
>   21:55:16,443] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=console-consumer-5221] Connection to node -1
>   (kafka/23.202.231.166:9092) could not be established. Broker may not
>   be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2019-06-03
>   21:55:16,721] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=console-consumer-5221] Connection to node -1
>   (kafka/23.202.231.166:9092) could not be established. Broker may not
>   be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2019-06-03
>   21:55:17,145] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=console-consumer-5221] Connection to node -1
>   (kafka/23.202.231.166:9092) could not be established. Broker may not
>   be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2019-06-03
>   21:55:18,017] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=console-consumer-5221] Connection to node -1
>   (kafka/23.202.231.166:9092) could not be established. Broker may not
>   be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) ^CProcessed a
>   total of 0 messages
>
> $ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
>   --topic dbserver1.public.publications
>
> [2019-06-03 21:55:16,180] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1,
>   groupId=console-consumer-5221] Connection to node -1
>   (kafka/23.202.231.166:9092) could not be established. Broker may not
>   be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

How do I specify the correct value for bootstrap-server? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to Kafka running in Docker from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker-from-local-machine)

Comment: Your host machine doesn't know what `kafka:9092` is, only the Docker network does... Did you mean to use localhost like you did for Zookeeper?

Comment: Yes, I meant to use localhost, but if you see the output above, i tried with localhost:9092 and it has the same problem

Comment: Your advertised listeners are incorrectly configured, then. The Debezium docker examples assume you run those commands within the container. Please refer to the duplicate post I marked... You can use any Kafka container with Debezium, it doesn't have to be one they provide

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to connect to kafka broker from an external server.

Since you have already mentioned your Kafka and Zookeeper instances are running from docker images. You need to identify your docker images external port corresponding to 9092 as well as its external IP address and you have to those along with --bootstrap-server parameter while executing command `kafka-console-consumer.sh`

Comment: everything is running on my mac , i.e. localhost.   The kafka docker instance is started with :  docker run -it — name kafka -p 9092:9092 — link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka  .    However why cannot I use localhost:9092 for the bootstrap-server as shown in the output above. I first tried kafka:9092 and then localhost:9092 as shown above .  Thanks for help.

Comment: @Anand Kafka networking doesn't work with just a simple port forward https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the `kafka-console-consumer.sh` outside of docker then you should use `localhost` hostname. If inside the Docker container then make sure it is in container that sees `kafka` hostname.