# producer fails on org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic topicTest not present in metadata after 60000 ms

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm trying to produce messages to a kafka container and it seems to fail on produce.
connection seems OK.

```
docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
zookeeper:
image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
ports:
- "2181:2181"
environment:
- ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
kafka:
build: .
ports:
- "9092:9092"
- "9093:9093"
environment:
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9093,EXTERNAL://127.0.0.1:9092
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9093,EXTERNAL://127.0.0.1:9092
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
volumes:
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

tried with both :

```
.\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list 0.0.0.0:9092 --topic topicTest
and
.\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topicTest
```

netstat shows listening on the port.

```
.\kafka-topics.bat --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topicTest 
Topic:topicTest PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
Topic: topicTest Partition: 0 Leader: 1001 Replicas: 1001 Isr: 1001
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to Kafka running in Docker from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker-from-local-machine)

Comment: 0.0.0.0:9092 isn't a real address. And the advertised listeners should take priority over advertised hostname

Comment: hi @cricket_007, the 0.0.0.0 was just for testing. also the advertised hostname. removing them doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Found my issue!!!!

I've changed the following :

```
KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9093,EXTERNAL://127.0.0.1:9092
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9093,EXTERNAL://127.0.0.1:9092
```

into:

```
KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9092
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9093,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
```

and it worked.

I guess that the KAFKA_LISTENERS property should not have addressed the localhost or something.

Comment: listeners should just be `<protocol>://0.0.0.0:<port>`. Then you are telling the container to bind on all interfaces. The advertised listeners are how the clients actually communicate with that broker