# 500 Internal Server Error Error while creating AdminClient for Cluster Default

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I get an error when I try to view topics and consumers using UI for apache kafka

docker command i use:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER=2181:2181 -e KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=127.0.0.1:9092 -d provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
```

or docker-compose.yml file

```html
services:
  kafka-ui:
    container_name: kafka-ui
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka:9092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_JMXPORT: 9997

  kafka:
    image: johnnypark/kafka-zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "9092:9092"
    network_mode: bridge
    environment:
      ADVERTISED_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      NUM_PARTITIONS: 1
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

**I tried both ways, both didn't work**

**Where did i go wrong?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the johnnypark/kafka-zookeeper library for both kafka and zookeeper. I was able to solve this problem by using two separate libraries as in the example below

```html
  zookeeper1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.4
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper1
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
      - 9998:9998
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper1:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      JMX_PORT: 9998
      KAFKA_JMX_OPTS: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=kafka1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9998
```

https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui/blob/master/docker/kafka-ui.yaml

Answer (score 0):

`2181:2181` is two ports, not a Zookeeper hostname/ip and port

Then, Kafka address is referring to the container you're running, not the actual Kafka server. You'll need to modify your Kafka server properties if it's running on the host, and you need to connect from Docker. Related - [Connect to Kafka on host from Docker (ksqlDB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68401788/connect-to-kafka-on-host-from-docker-ksqldb)

Beyond that, remove the `-d` or use `docker logs` to see the actual error.

Comment: How can I look at the cluster name?

Comment: If you cannot `ping cloud_erp_backend_kafka_1`  from the host, then Docker cannot reach it either

Comment: so what should i do? :(

Comment: I don't know your network, but giving a full domain name rather than only a host would be a start. Talk to your server administrators that control your DNS settings