# Failed to start schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-schema-registry

I have followed this demo and get the following error.

https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-demo
https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-demo/blob/7.0.1-post/docker-compose.yml

I replace KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS with my own kafka server and get the following error, what could be the cause of this issue?

```
[2022-02-08 11:03:09,095] INFO Logging initialized @838ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log)
[2022-02-08 11:03:09,130] INFO Initial capacity 128, increased by 64, maximum capacity 2147483647. (io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer)
[2022-02-08 11:03:09,204] INFO Adding listener with HTTP/2: https://0.0.0.0:8085 (io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer)
[2022-02-08 11:03:09,491] ERROR Error starting the schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication)
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryException:  No listener configured with requested scheme http
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.getSchemeAndPortForIdentity(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:303)
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.<init>(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:148)
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.initSchemaRegistry(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:71)
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.configureBaseApplication(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:90)
  at io.confluent.rest.Application.configureHandler(Application.java:271)
  at io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer.doStart(ApplicationServer.java:245)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:44)
```

Comment: 1) The error has nothing to do with KSQL 2) Do you need SSL? If not, use this one https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.0.1-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml 3) You can run KSQL by itself without other components  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68401788/connect-to-kafka-on-host-from-docker-ksqldb

Comment: thank you very much @OneCricketeer  It really helps.