# Provectus Kafka-UI for Kafka service

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

There is opensource Kafka UI https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui but it distributed as Docker image, I have not understand how this isolated environment working with Kafka services on local machine, local machine has Kafka service and Zookeeper service, it has config can management by start/stop. And what relation for this services and isolated site inside Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it distributed as Docker image

You can also clone the source code and build with Maven, then run the created JAR application.

---

> not understand how this isolated environment working with Kafka services on local machine

You would connect to `host.docker.internal`. Ref [Connect to Kafka on host from Docker (ksqlDB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68401788/connect-to-kafka-on-host-from-docker-ksqldb)