# Apache Airflow - Apache Kafka automation

Tags: python, apache-kafka, airflow

Here is the situation.
I have installed Apache Kafka in my local machine. I have installed Apache Airflow on docker (bcz I am not able to install it on local machine).
I want to run Apache Airflow on top of Apache Kafka producer(written in Python) and Apache Kafka consumer(written in python) to automate this. How can I?
Because airflow is running on docker and kafka is running on local machine.

I tried to run airflow on AWS EC2 instance and it didnt work. I think due to some port conflicts.

Comment: Please show what you've tried? Kafka could also run in Docker, by the way, but you'll still have to show what Python code you've tried to connect Airflow to it. Related question for connection from Docker https://stackoverflow.com/a/68412602/2308683

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.