# Producer cannot connect to kafka in docker compose in Docker Desktop on mac

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm working on Mac with Docker Desktop. I'm trying to run `wurstmeister/kafka` from docker compose and connect a producer to it.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: zookeeper:3.7.0
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zookeeper:2888:3888;2181
    restart: on-failure

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.7.0
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:19092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:19092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

Then I have producer connecting to `localhost:9092` and sending a simple message. The producer works fine - tested with another kafka image `confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0`.

When I try to use producer with `wurstmeister/kafka` I'm getting a lot of this errors:

```
22:07:13.421 [kafka-producer-network-thread | simple-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=simple-producer] Initialize connection to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
22:07:13.421 [kafka-producer-network-thread | simple-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=simple-producer] Initiating connection to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) using address localhost/127.0.0.1
22:07:13.421 [kafka-producer-network-thread | simple-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Producer clientId=simple-producer] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 326640, SO_SNDBUF = 146988, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
22:07:13.421 [kafka-producer-network-thread | simple-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=simple-producer] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
22:07:13.421 [kafka-producer-network-thread | simple-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=simple-producer] Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
22:07:13.422 [kafka-producer-network-thread | simple-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=simple-producer] Sending API_VERSIONS request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=simple-producer, correlationId=20) and timeout 30000 to node -1: {client_software_name=apache-kafka-java,client_software_version=2.7.0,_tagged_fields={}}
22:07:13.423 [kafka-producer-network-thread | simple-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Producer clientId=simple-producer] Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:447)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:397)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:561)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:325)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:240)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
22:07:13.424 [kafka-producer-network-thread | simple-producer] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=simple-producer] Node -1 disconnected.
22:07:13.424 [kafka-producer-network-thread | simple-producer] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=simple-producer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Why this happens? What is the cause of this error? And how can make it work?

EDIT: added kafka container logs

Kafka container last logs below and no new logs added when I try to connect producer:

```
[2021-09-09 21:07:28,227] INFO Kafka version: 2.7.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-09-09 21:07:28,230] INFO Kafka commitId: 448719dc99a19793 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-09-09 21:07:28,231] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1631221648211 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2021-09-09 21:07:28,238] INFO [KafkaServer id=1] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-09-09 21:07:28,365] INFO [broker-1-to-controller-send-thread]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker 1 (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
```

Comment: Can you show logs from the Kafka container?

Comment: @clarj I edited the question and added logs

Comment: Can you try use the console consumer and producer? Start a couple of terminals and attach to ```kafka```. On one subscribe to a topic like ```kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test``` and produce with the other using ```kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test```. Send some messages and see if you see them on the consumer. If not then it seems potentially a Kafka fault rather than a networking fault etc.

Comment: The environment variables are not consistent across Kafka Docker images. If all you did was switch the image tag value, then you need to make sure the variables are correct as well - [Connect to Kafka in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker)

Comment: @OneCricketeer Hmm from what I can see there, there are not much differences? Can you spot any errors in my configuration?

Comment: KAFKA_LISTENERS needs to be `0.0.0.0:9092` for the external config... (mentioned in the other answer) Otherwise, you're telling the container to only allow connections to itself, not external networks. This is the default on the Confluent images

Comment: Thanks! Can you make it an answer so I can vote it up and mark as good answer?