# Spring Kafka: UnknownHostException: 34bcfcc207e0

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I wrote kafka producer / consumer for my app:

Consumer config:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    fun consumerFactory(): ConsumerFactory<String, String> {
        val props: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        props[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "http://localhost:9092"
        props[ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG] = "group12345"
        props[ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java
        props[ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java
        return DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(props)
    }

    @Bean
    fun kafkaListenerContainerFactory(): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> {
        val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>()
        factory.consumerFactory = consumerFactory()
        return factory
    }
}
```

Producer config:

```
@Configuration
class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Bean
    fun producerFactory(): ProducerFactory<String, String> {
        val configProps: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        configProps[ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "http://localhost:9092"
        configProps[ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java
        configProps[ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java
        return DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(configProps)
    }

    @Bean
    fun kafkaTemplate(): KafkaTemplate<String, String> {
        return KafkaTemplate(producerFactory())
    }
}
```

Topic config:

```
@Configuration
class KafkaTopicConfig {

    @Bean
    fun kafkaAdmin(): KafkaAdmin {
        val configs: MutableMap<String, Any?> = HashMap()
        configs[AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "http://localhost:9092"
        return KafkaAdmin(configs)
    }

    @Bean
    fun topic1(): NewTopic {
        return NewTopic("kafkaTest", 1, 1.toShort())
    }
}
```

Kafka service:

```
@Service
class KafkaService(
    private val kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, String>
) {

    fun send() {
        kafkaTemplate.send("kafkaTest", "test message ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = ["kafkaTest"], groupId = "group12345")
    fun listenGroupFoo(message: String) {
        println("--> $message")
    }
}
```

That's ALL classes in my app. When I trying to run app, I get this exception:

> 2021-10-11 17:20:13.319  WARN 8544 --- [| adminclient-1]
> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient
> clientId=adminclient-1] Error connecting to node 34bcfcc207e0:9092
> (id: 1001 rack: null)
>
> java.net.UnknownHostException: 34bcfcc207e0

I have no idea, what is host `34bcfcc207e0`. It appears at start or thread.

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Try adding "localhost:2181" to your "bootstrapservers" in consumer config . This is to add consumers to zookeeper for consumer re-balancing and registering with zookeeper

Comment: Is the Kafka broker running inside Docker? Is the Kafka broker running inside a Docker container with container ID 34bcfcc207e0?

Comment: It's called a bootstrap server for just that reason; the client initially connects to that address, and the server returns the actual host name(s) to connect to; when using docker, you need to configure Kafka's advertised hosts within the container.

Comment: yes, it is container name...

Comment: @Umeshwaran Kafka clients do not use Zookeeper as bootstrap servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Kafka is not an HTTP service. Remove `http://` from all your strings
2. If you're running Kafka in a Container, the default advertised listener is using its hostname (the container ID), and you need to change this to use an address you expect [Connect to Kafka running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue using docker-compose, at the beginning I didn't know  where it came from that hash id either, then I realized it corresponded to the container id, and by default the `hostname` of my broker service.

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID   PORTS                              NAMES
   b6d781c2089b   2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp   broker-1
* fac6ef279a3e   2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9093->9092/tcp   broker-2
  cbbc73bfe92e   0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp             zookeeper
```

log

```
broker-2 | Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker fac6ef279a3e:9092
```

When I tried to connect with my Java consumer using:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092,localhost:9093");
```

gets the following error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: fac6ef279a3e
```

I solved it as follows

adding a hostname to each broker

```
services:
  ...
  broker-1:
    hostname: broker-1
    ports:
     - "9092:9092"
   ...
  broker-2:
    hostname: broker-2
    ports:
     - "9093:9092"
```

setting my /etc/hosts like:

```
#### kafka
127.0.0.1   broker-1
127.0.0.1   broker-2
```

and my props connection

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"broker-1:9092,broker-2:9093");
```