# cant connect make request from fastapi container to kafka container

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka

I have two containers one is kafka container open port 9092:9092 and another is Fastapi container. If I don't dockerize Fastapi, I can make rest api request to fastapi to kafka. It sends message to kafka via fastapi. But when I dockerize fastapi can't connect fastapi container to kafka container.
I cant run fastapi docker file with -p 8000:8000 -p 9092:9092 it says 9092 is already used.

How can I make request to fastapi container then fastapi connects to kafka container.

fastapi dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.10

ADD . .

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

My error is

`kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable`.

I get kafka container IP address and I am making to kafka container IP address example

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=containerip, value_serializer=lambda x: json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8'),api_version=(2)), lines=True, orient='records')
```

Comment: Because you've shown no error or your actual Python code. For example, Kafka is no longer available at localhost:9092 if you containerize your api

Answer (score 0):

> cant run fastapi docker file with -p 8000:8000 -p 9092:9092 it says 9092 is already used.

Remove it then. Unclear why you need port 9092 on your API, anyway ; it's not the Kafka service.

Without seeing your complete Kafka client code, it's hard to say what your other problems are, so please consult [Connect to Kafka running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker)

For example, what is `containerip`? This should be `kafka:9092` (if you follow the instructions in the linked post)

1. Run `docker network create`
2. Make sure you use `docker run` with `--network` on both containers
3. Ensure `KAFKA_ADVERTISTED_LISTENERS` variable contains at least `INTERNAL://kafka:9092`
4. Remove the `-p` flags for the Kafka container since you are only interacting with Kafka from another container.
5. Connect Python to `kafka:9092`

Comment: I am running fastapi container with docker run -p 8000:8000 it is working fine . Also kafka container is running opened 9092:9092 but When I make request fastapi to kafka it gives me this error kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable. I get kafka container IP address and I am making to kafka container IP address example producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=containerip,                         
                        value_serializer=lambda x: 
                        json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8'),api_version=(2)), lines=True, orient='records')

Comment: You should not be using IP addresses when you are using Docker, as linked in the other answer - https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/ Plus, between containers the `-p` flag or the numbers listed afterwards do not do anything.

Answer (score -2):

If you set network mode of your container to host, it's done.

run your fast-api (pay attention to `network` switch):

```sh
docker run --network host -p 8000:8000 fast-api
```

run kafka:

```sh
docker run -p 9092:9092 kafka
```

run postgres:

```sh
docker run -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

but it's better to use [bridge-networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/).

Comment: I can connect to kafka container with fast api. but when I made fast api container. it is not connecting to kafka.

Comment: you can create network for this.
https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Comment: Actually i found the kafka container Ip address and connect to it. But now give me nobrokersavailable error.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't work with kafka.

Comment: Kafka can't be run with no environment variables