# Cannot connect to the Kafka docker instance

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, bitnami

I am using bitnami/kafka:latest and bitnami/zookeper:latest images.

My sample project in Github: https://github.com/KostasD21/kafka-docker-demo

if you run the command docker-compose up and then run the application, you will see that the Spring Boot application cannot connect to the kafka container (which is currently running under the host kafka:9092)

The stacktrace from the application:

```
2022-05-31 08:59:18.255  WARN 144414 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-foo-1, groupId=foo] Error connecting to node kafka:9092 (id: 1001 rack: null)

java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1367) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1301) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.DefaultHostResolver.resolve(DefaultHostResolver.java:27) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:110) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:511) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:468) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:173) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:979) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$600(NetworkClient.java:73) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1152) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1040) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:549) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:227) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:164) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:258) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:483) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1262) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1231) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1520) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1510) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1338) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1247) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar:2.8.4]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

logs from the docker container:

```
2022-05-31 05:51:24,236] INFO [RequestSendThread controllerId=1001] Starting (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,236] INFO [Controller id=1001] Currently active brokers in the cluster: Set(1001) (kafka.controller.KafkaController)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,236] INFO [Controller id=1001] Currently shutting brokers in the cluster: Set() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,237] INFO [Controller id=1001] Current list of topics in the cluster: Set(__consumer_offsets, test-topic) (kafka.controller.KafkaController)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,237] INFO [Controller id=1001] Fetching topic deletions in progress (kafka.controller.KafkaController)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,241] INFO [Controller id=1001] List of topics to be deleted:  (kafka.controller.KafkaController)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,241] INFO [Controller id=1001] List of topics ineligible for deletion:  (kafka.controller.KafkaController)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,241] INFO [Controller id=1001] Initializing topic deletion manager (kafka.controller.KafkaController)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,242] INFO [Topic Deletion Manager 1001] Initializing manager with initial deletions: Set(), initial ineligible deletions: Set() (kafka.controller.TopicDeletionManager)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,242] INFO [Controller id=1001] Sending update metadata request (kafka.controller.KafkaController)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,243] INFO [ExpirationReaper--1-AlterAcls]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,244] INFO [Controller id=1001 epoch=3] Sending UpdateMetadata request to brokers Set(1001) for 0 partitions (state.change.logger)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,249] INFO [ReplicaStateMachine controllerId=1001] Initializing replica state (kafka.controller.ZkReplicaStateMachine)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,252] INFO [ReplicaStateMachine controllerId=1001] Triggering online replica state changes (kafka.controller.ZkReplicaStateMachine)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,253] INFO [RequestSendThread controllerId=1001] Controller 1001 connected to kafka:9092 (id: 1001 rack: null) for sending state change requests (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)[2022-05-31 05:51:24,258] INFO [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.common.ZkNodeChangeNotificationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread)
```

Currently I am stuck on this communication. The problem has to do with docker networking probably but I am not an expert on this aspect.

Comment: Where is the Spring Boot application running? Is it in a container or in the host?

Comment: The application is running on localhost

Comment: I would argue **this is not a duplicate** because it pertains the `docker-compose` setup while the other question pertains the `docker` cli: although the cause of the issue is the same the solution is different.

Comment: Adding my answer as comment because answers are blocked because this issue was marked as duplicate: in your `docker-compose.yml` under `kafka: environment:` add or edit the line to look like this `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51634499/19059974

From the point of view of your application, Kafka is listening in `localhost` (`kafka` hostname would be if it is running in within the same docker network)

Essentially, you need to add a protocol mapper and a listener that announces that kafka is reachable at localhost (see previous answer), change the port where your kafka container binds to `29092` (in your docker-compose file) and have your app connect to `localhost:29092`