# Debezium/Kafka Connect not exporting snapshot data of my MySQL table

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm trying to get debezium to run on Local MySQL instance after managing to get it to work on a cloud hosted MySQL server and it's not taking/exporting the snapshot of my target database, despite doing so for my cloud hosted MySQL.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
volumes:
  mysql-data:
  mysql-log:
  mysql-conf:
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:latest
    
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  kafka-connect:
    image: docker.io/debezium/connect:latest
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - mysql
    environment:
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
      - GROUP_ID=1
      - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my-connect-configs
      - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my-connect-offsets
      - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my-connect-statuses
  nmap:
    image: docker.io/instrumentisto/nmap
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - kafka-connect
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka:9092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_JMXPORT: 9997
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb
      - MYSQL_USER=test
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - mysql-log:/var/log/mysql
      - mysql-conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - /Users/Name/repos/debezium/custom-config.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom-config.cnf:ro
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 20s
      retries: 10
  consumer:
    image: python-kafka-consumer:latest
```

I had issues with my local MySQL user and it's Grants so I set Super_priv, Repl_client_priv and Repl_slave_priv to 'Y' using these queries:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Super_Priv='Y' WHERE user='test' AND host='%';
UPDATE mysql.user SET Repl_client_priv='Y' WHERE user='test' AND host='%';
UPDATE mysql.user SET Repl_slave_priv='Y' WHERE user='test' AND host='%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Below are the commands I used up to this point. Any help would be much appreciated!

I've ran the curl command to register the Debezium MySQL Connector pointed at my test table in my Local MySQL :

```
    curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" 
    -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ 
    -d '{ "name": "local-mysql-test-connector", "config": { "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector", 
            "tasks.max": "1", "database.hostname": "host.docker.internal",
        "database.port": "3306", "database.user": "test", 
        "database.password": "test", "database.server.id": "100",
        "database.server.name": "local_mysql", "database.include.list": "testdb.Persons", "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.mysql" } }'
```

This is the curl command for the Cloud MySQL Connector:

```
        curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{ "name": "test-connector",
    "config": { "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1", "database.hostname": "host.docker.internal",
    "database.port": "3310", "database.user": "user",
    "database.password": "password", "database.server.id": "4564865", "database.server.name": "test_server", "database.include.list": "testDB", "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.testDB" } }'
```

Then in the Debezium/Kafka Connect logs, it displays that it reads the test db ('testdb') that I aiming it to but it doesn't take the snapshot of the table, nor does it export that snapshot.

```
MySQL|local_mysql|snapshot  Snapshot step 7 - Snapshotting data   [io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource]

MySQL|local_mysql|snapshot  Snapshotting contents of 0 tables while still in transaction   [io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource]
```

and then in the snapshot result it confirms this with:

```
tableIds=[null], databaseName=testdb]
```

Where as the Connector connected to the Cloud MySQL both picks up the table it's pointed to, takes a snapshot of it and exports it correctly:

```
MySQL|test_server|snapshot  Snapshot step 7 - Snapshotting data   [io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource]
MySQL|test_server|snapshot  Snapshotting contents of 1 tables while still in transaction   [io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource]
MySQL|test_server|snapshot  Exporting data from table 'testDB.test_table' (1 of 1 tables)   [io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource]
MySQL|test_server|snapshot        For table 'testDB.test_table' using select statement: 'SELECT `id`, `event_code`, `event_date`, `created_at`, `modified_at` FROM `testDB`.`test_table`'   [io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource]
MySQL|test_server|snapshot        Finished exporting 18 records for table 'testDB.test_table'; total duration '00:00:00.087'   [io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource]
MySQL|test_server|snapshot  Snapshot - Final stage   [io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource]
MySQL|test_server|snapshot  Snapshot ended with SnapshotResult [status=COMPLETED, offset=MySqlOffsetContext [sourceInfoSchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.mysql.Source:STRUCT}, sourceInfo=SourceInfo [currentGtid=null, currentBinlogFilename=mysql-bin.003725, currentBinlogPosition=62104189, currentRowNumber=0, serverId=0, sourceTime=2022-06-25T18:37:49.244Z, threadId=-1, currentQuery=null, tableIds=[testDB.test_table], databaseName=youth_economy], snapshotCompleted=true, transactionContext=TransactionContext [currentTransactionId=null, perTableEventCount={}, totalEventCount=0], restartGtidSet=c7bbd9dd-bf97-11e9-8a95-42010a2d0007:1-38268404, currentGtidSet=c7bbd9dd-bf97-11e9-8a95-42010a2d0007:1-38268404, restartBinlogFilename=mysql-bin.003725, restartBinlogPosition=62104189, restartRowsToSkip=0, restartEventsToSkip=0, currentEventLengthInBytes=0, inTransaction=false, transactionId=null, incrementalSnapshotContext =IncrementalSnapshotContext [windowOpened=false, chunkEndPosition=null, dataCollectionsToSnapshot=[], lastEventKeySent=null, maximumKey=null]]]   [io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator]
    
2022-06-25 18:37:49,428 INFO   MySQL|test_server|binlog  Connected to MySQL binlog at host.docker.internal:3310, starting at MySqlOffsetContext [sourceInfoSchema=Schema{io.debezium.connector.mysql.Source:STRUCT}, sourceInfo=SourceInfo [currentGtid=null, currentBinlogFilename=mysql-bin.003725, currentBinlogPosition=62104189, currentRowNumber=0, serverId=0, sourceTime=2022-06-25T18:37:49.244Z, threadId=-1, currentQuery=null, **tableIds=[testDB.test_table]**, databaseName=youth_economy], snapshotCompleted=true, transactionContext=TransactionContext [currentTransactionId=null, perTableEventCount={}, totalEventCount=0], restartGtidSet=c7bbd9dd-bf97-11e9-8a95-42010a2d0007:1-38268404, currentGtidSet=c7bbd9dd-bf97-11e9-8a95-42010a2d0007:1-38268404, restartBinlogFilename=mysql-bin.003725, restartBinlogPosition=62104189, restartRowsToSkip=0, restartEventsToSkip=0, currentEventLengthInBytes=0, inTransaction=false, transactionId=null, incrementalSnapshotContext =IncrementalSnapshotContext [windowOpened=false, chunkEndPosition=null, dataCollectionsToSnapshot=[], lastEventKeySent=null, maximumKey=null]]   [io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlStreamingChangeEventSource]
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: If everything is local on docker, I dont think you need to redact it. I suggest you try running [mysql within a docker container as well, and follow the tutorial](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/main/tutorial/README.md#using-mysql)

Comment: @OneCricketeer Everything is local on docker. But I hear your point about the redaction. I've unredacted the values and added my docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Thanks, but do you get similar errors following the linked tutorial? If you're running mysql within docker, then `host.docker.internal` is not correct for either environment

Comment: @onecricketeer If I follow the linked tutorial without using containers then I don't receive the same snapshot errors as above, but the kafka consumers don't receive the messages. re: the `host.docker.internal` - what should it be then - `localhost`?

Comment: The linked guide does use Docker, so I'm not sure what you mean. And no, the hostname of the mysql container is just `mysql` https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/  Regarding the consumer issues you mention, please read through this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker#51634499