# Setting Kafka Consumer Level Configuration in Docker Compose File

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have a situation where I have two docker compose files: one contains, among other things, a Kafka image; the other contains some other process which consumes from Kafka.

`kakfa.yaml`:

```
version: "3.4" 
services:   
  zookeeper:
    image: "wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest"
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    restart: on-failure

  kafka:
    image: "wurstmeister/kafka:latest"
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9093:9093"
      - "19092:19092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: "9092"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9093"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "INTERNAL"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    restart: on-failure
```

`processor.yaml`

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  processor:
    build: .
    environment:
      - LOGURU_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - MQ_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER=kafka
      - MQ_BOOTSTRAP_PORT=9092
    ports:
      - "8801:80"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./service:/app/service
    entrypoint: [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ]
    command: |
      "
      kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic example_topic
      "
```

My `command` attempt at the bottom of `processor.yaml` gives the following error in docker: `/bin/sh: 2: kafka-console-consumer: not found`.

Is there a way I can set Consumer configs within `processor.yaml`?

Edit: my dockerfile for both yaml files

```
ENV APP_PATH=/app
ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${APP_PATH}"

COPY requirements.txt "${APP_PATH}/requirements.txt"
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir  -r "${APP_PATH}/requirements.txt"

COPY . $APP_PATH
WORKDIR $APP_PATH
```

Comment: Without seeing your Dockerfile is a bit hard but I would try with the full path to `kafka-console-consumer` and also make sure that `processor` runs in the same docker network so you can use `kafka:9092` instead of `localhost:9092` (it will be way easier than trying to reach kafka from a different docker network or through your host network)

Comment: The full path I have for kafka (shown on docker desktop) is `/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/kafka/bin` but this seems to give the same error. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: can you paste your processor `Dockerfile` in the question?

Comment: Of course! Both have the same docker file.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not related to "consumer configs". Your Dockerfile appears to be a Python container. You have not installed the Kafka CLI tools there such that `kafka-console-consumer.sh` command would be available.

To have the Kafka CLI tools, you'd also need to install Java in that container, which would cause your image to be larger than necessary. Instead, you should write a consumer in a Python client, then run your own `python consumer.py` as your container command.

Also, `localhost:9092` is not referring to the Kafka container. Related - [Connect to Kafka running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker)

Otherwise, you don't need a different container to run `kafka-console-consumer`; you can `docker-compose exec kafka bash -c "kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 ... "`