# Trying to connect a containerized spring boot app with an containerized kafka server

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka

I have a Spring Boot application which worked fine with Kafka in a container but when I containerize the Spring Boot application it won't work.

This is the docker-compose file with which I created

```yaml
version: "3.4"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper
    restart: always
    container_name: "zookeeper"
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "zookeeper_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    restart: always
    container_name: "kafka"
    volumes:
      - "kafka_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
```

The `application.yml` of the Spring Boot application

```yaml
server:
  port: 5001

spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysql-container:3306/craproject?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: ***
    password: ****


  data:
    mongodb:
      host: mongo-container
      port: 27017
      database: craprojet


  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers:
      - kafka:9092
    consumer:
      group-id: project-group
      enable-auto-commit: false
      auto-offset-reset: latest
      isolation-level: read_committed
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer

    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

The dockerfile with which I created the image of the app:

```
FROM openjdk:11
COPY target/project-service-1.jar  project-service-1.jar
EXPOSE 5001
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar" , "project-service-1.jar"]
```

The containers of kafka and data bases are running fine :
[image]

[image]

This is the command which i use to run the spring boot app container :

```bash
docker run --name project-service\
  --network techbankNet\ 
  -p 5001:5001\ 
  --link mysql-container:mysql\
  --link mongo-container:mongo\
  --link adminer:adminer\
  --link kafka:kafka project-service
```

the log:

```
2022-08-23 19:05:05.170  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
        allow.auto.create.topics = true
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = latest
        bootstrap.servers = [kafka:9092]
        check.crcs = true
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id = consumer-project-group-1
        client.rack =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        enable.auto.commit = false
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        group.id = project-group
        group.instance.id = null
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        interceptor.classes = []
        internal.leave.group.on.close = true
        internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
        isolation.level = read_committed
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
        max.poll.records = 500
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        session.timeout.ms = 10000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 127000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        value.deserializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer

2022-08-23 19:05:15.315  WARN 1 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils     : Couldn't resolve server kafka:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka
2022-08-23 19:05:15.316  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics scheduler closed
2022-08-23 19:05:15.316  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2022-08-23 19:05:15.317  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics reporters closed
2022-08-23 19:05:15.319  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.consumer for consumer-project-group-1 unregistered
2022-08-23 19:05:15.319  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextExcepti
on: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
2022-08-23 19:05:15.340  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-23 19:05:15.343  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-08-23 19:05:15.365  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-08-23 19:05:15.368  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-08-23 19:05:15.389  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-23 19:05:15.420 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct 
kafka consumer
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar!/:2.5.3]
        at com.project.CQRS.ProjectServiceApplication.main(ProjectServiceApplication.java:16) ~[classes!/:1]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[project-service-1.jar:1]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[project-service-1.jar:1]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[project-service-1.jar:1]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[project-service-1.jar:1]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:819) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createRawConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:366) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:334) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:310) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:277) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:254) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:715) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:320) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:397) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:205) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:397) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:327) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:272) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:89) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:728) ~[kafka-clients-2.7.1.jar!/:na]
```

Comment: I think that `:9092` is the port that clients *outside* of the Docker network can connect to your Kafka broker. You need to set up an internal port - see [Accessing Apache Kafka with internal and external clients](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka#accessing-apache-kafka-with-internal-and-external-clients)

Comment: @aSemy No, `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` is setting the internal port correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `project-service` (and adminer, mongo, and mysql) in the same Docker Compose file as Kafka and not use `docker run`.

This will create a default bridge network where the containers can talk to each other.

Or you need to attach `techbankNet` Docker network to the Kafka service in the compose file.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Also see [Connect to Kafka running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker)

Comment: mongodb container and mysql container are working fine and i have created a network and i set it to every container network, every think worked fine till i cauterized the spring boot app

Comment: You've not shown your other three container configs, but `--network techbankNet` is not attached to the Kafka container, therefore, you have `No resolvable bootstrap urls given` ... `Couldn't resolve server kafka:9092`

Comment: thanks it worked but i had to add some configurations:

`KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_INSIDE://0.0.0.0:29092,LISTENER_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS:LISTENER_INSIDE://kafka:29092,LISTENER_HOST://kafka:9092
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP:LISTENER_INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_HOST:PLAINTEXT
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_INSIDE
KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: " -Xmx256m -Xms256m"`

Comment: Looks okay, but `LISTENER_HOST` should be `lcoalhost:9092`