# No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers on maven install

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am building up a jar file for my spring boot microservice, but upon maven install i am getting the error as stated below.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:89) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:730) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.1.jar:na]
```

my docker-compose file for the application is

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    networks:
      - app-network

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    networks:
      - app-network

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb
    networks:
      - app-network
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  matching-engine-helper:
    image: matching-engine-helper:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: "matching-engine-helper"
    networks:
      - app-network
    ports:
      - 9192:9192
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - zookeeper
      - kafka

  matching-engine-core:
    image: matching-engine-core:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: "matching-engine-core"
    networks:
      - app-network
    ports:
      - 9191:9191
    depends_on:
      - matching-engine-helper
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - mongodb

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

and the application.yml is

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: matching-engine-mongodb
      host: mongodb
      port: 27017
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: kafka:9092
server:
  port: 9192
```

let me know if i need some environment variable's configuration here. as its running fine on local environment on local host but not on docker containers as i am unable to make a jar out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `mvn install` is running on your host, then your host [doesn't know how to resolve `kafka` as a DNS name running in a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker). It that's what you wanted, then you should rename your file to  `application-docker.yml` and use Spring profiles to properly override any defaults when you actually do run your code in a container. In your case, you would need to have `localhost:29092` for Kafka, and similarly use `localhost:27017` for Mongo in your default `application.yml`. You can also use environment variables for those two properties rather than hard-code them.

Or, if `mvn install` is running in a Docker layer itself, then that is completely isolated from other Docker networks. You can pass `--network` flag to `docker build`, though.

Assuming you don't want to `mvn install -DskipTests`, **ideally**, your tests do not rely on external services to be running. If you want to run a Kafka unit test, which is failing to connect, then you should either mock that, or using Spring-Kafka's EmbeddedKafka for integration-tests.

Worth mentioning that Spring boot has a Maven plugin for building Docker images, and it doesn't need a JAR to do so.