# I cannot connect to kafka using a test container while the integration is writing a test

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, testcontainers, spring-kafka-test, testcontainers-junit5

using testcontainer; I'm trying to write an integration test for my project with kafka, postgreSql and elasticsearch, but when I run [docker-compose_v2.yml](https://github.com/semihshn/gateway-server/blob/main/docker-compose_v2.yml) file and run [my tests](https://github.com/semihshn/driver-service/blob/main/src/test/java/com/semihshn/driverservice/integration/driver/steps/RetrieveDriverByIdFeatureSteps.java), my tests are successful, but when I use testcontainer, [my test](https://github.com/semihshn/driver-service/blob/main/src/test/java/com/semihshn/driverservice/integration/driver/steps/RetrieveDriverByIdFeatureSteps.java)s fail, I can't connect to kafka while the tests are running.

Comment: Please add your code as a [mcve] to the question, not external links. Also, your tests links are the exact same, so its not clear what is failing

Comment: Hi, I've corrected my docker-compose file to allow services to communicate with each other, not through static IP, but with the service name. In fact, before I asked this question, I tried to run my integration tests using the docker-compose module you shared with me, but what I didn't understand was, is that my application with the containers running by the test containers is transacting on the same network, so broker: 29092 or localhost: 9092, I couldn't decide which one of the following addresses to request

Comment: Where do your tests actually run? That decides which to connect to. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker#51634499

Comment: If you are asking if my tests are running in the cloud or running on my local computer, I run them on my local computer, but I do not know if my tests and test containers are running on the same network, I know that Kafka accepts requests from different ports if they are running on the same network or on a different network, but the answer to the above question I can't find a solution because I don't know

Answer (score 1):

Docker Compose should not use IP addresses. You should use Service names directly for endpoint resolution.

Your Compose file is not attached to the TestContainer network when you use `Network.newNetwork()`.

If you want to use Compose in your tests, then do that, not run individual GenericContainers - https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/docker_compose/

Comment: i've updated my project again and i've tried to run test container using docker-compose, but this way the tests can't connect to the skull while they're running.

Comment: logs =>

2022-09-22 03:16:13.053  WARN 17564 --- [ntainer#5-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-driver-group-4, groupId=driver-group] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-09-22 03:16:13.053  WARN 17564 --- [ntainer#5-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-driver-group-4, groupId=driver-group] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

Comment: test docker-compose file =>
https://github.com/semihshn/driver-service/blob/main/src/test/resources/test-compose.yml

integration tests =>
https://github.com/semihshn/driver-service/blob/main/src/test/java/com/semihshn/driverservice/integration/driver/steps/RetrieveDriverByIdFeatureSteps.java

Comment: I cannot tell which of those tests actually uses Kafka container

Comment: Why do you need to know that? Does the testcontainer library correctly run external applications, such as Kafka, which my application uses? Were the Testcontainers properly carried out?

Comment: Refer [mcve]. If your question is related to Kafka, please show that, not some stack of 4+ interconnected services. From your integration test link, I see you using Elasticsearch and some HTTP requests, and nothing doing Kafka things