# Kafka consumer disconnected from kafka cli

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I a consuming Kafka messages from Kafka cli with following command
**kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --from-beginning --topic mytopic --consumer.config ....\config\consumer.properties**

and I am getting following errors

```
[2022-09-23 15:59:33,175] WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=group] Bootstrap broker kafka:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-09-23 15:59:54,344] WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=group] Connection to node -1 (kafka:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-09-23 15:59:54,345] WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=group] Bootstrap broker kafka:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-09-23 16:00:15,634] WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=group] Connection to node -1 (kafka:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

I have updated server.properties with following configuration

```
port = 9092
advertised.host.name = kafka
KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
```

Comment: `KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS` is a property of bitnami docker container, not Kafka itself... Where are you actually running Kafka? In a container, or not? Also, port and advertised.host.name are deprecated properties, and should be removed

Comment: If you are using bitnami Kafka container, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker#51634499