# what is mean 'PLAINTEXT_HOST'?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

i use kafka cluster using by docker container

```
  kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,zookeeper-3:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://61.125.196.42:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
```

and `KAKFA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` is host for external consumer,producer.

in this setting, what is difference `PLAINTEXT` and `PLAINTEXT_HOST`?

First only passed data on `61.125.196.42:29092` not `kafka-1:9092`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a name.

The only requirement for the host one is that it needs to be a name in the security protocol mapping since it's not a builtin protocol.

The difference is that one is for external clients, as you said. The other is only within the Docker network where `kafka-1` DNS name is actually resolvable, similar to your Zookeepers

Refer [Connect to Kafka running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker#51634499)