# KAFKA with docker : cluster offline but container are up according "to docker ps -a"

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm new with kafka and i'm trying to do something simple.

I run kafka with docker.
here is my docker-compose:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092-9094:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  kafkaui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: "kafka:9092"
```

As you can see, I put the My IP as 127.0.0.1 for **KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAMEE**

then i do:
`docker-compose up -d`
and i check `with docker ps -a` and I see this screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4OKh.png)

Then I raise the number of broker :
`docker-compose up --scale kafka=3 -d`
I check with `docker ps -a` and I see this screeshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMw0b.png)

on my browser, i go to : http://127.0.0.1:8080
and I see that I have 1 cluster offline, see screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAoul.png)

why???
I have an old computer:
linux mint 21, 4 Gb RAM, intel Core i3

Do I need more RAM?

Answer (score 0):

RAM is not the problem

It's offline because it cannot connect. `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1` + `ports: 9092:9092` means it only accept connections from the **external** host, not other containers. You will not be able to scale the container with that variable set, as it needs to be `kafka`, but it also cannot be hardcoded to `kafka` when you scale beyond one broker (in other words, each container needs a unique hostname). [This page covers more details](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/wiki/Connectivity). But, one solution is using `KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092` instead, and remove `ports` from Compose unless you really need connectivity outside of Docker.

There is no real benefit to running more than one broker on the same host, anyway.

Comment: For docker-compose, i changed the kafka part by removing port and adding the new environment variable:
`  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock `

In the brower, for a few seconds i can see the cluster is online but then it is offline again.
later i want to run a python script where i simulate production of topics: need outside connection?

Comment: If you only have one broker, [then you can use a port forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker). I don't use that UI tool, so I cannot help there.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to use markdown to pretify my docker compose

Comment: Within a comment, you can't