# Valid Values for Kafka Inter Broker Protocol Version

Tags: apache-kafka

There are different valid values for `inter.broker.protocol.version` in the documentation on the [Kafka project](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_2_8_1) and the [Confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#inter-broker-protocol-version). The value `2.7`on the [Kafka page](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_2_8_1) should be either `2.7-IV1` or `2.7-IV2` according to the [docs on confluent.io](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#inter-broker-protocol-version).

Is this something specific to the `confluentinc/cp-kafka` image? Which one should I use when using the `confluentinc/cp-kafka` image?

Answer (score 0):

Confluent is only a distribution of Apache Kafka. Those values can be the same.

As for the container, it really doesn't matter which Kafka image you use, as `server.properties` is still used, regardless. Related - [Connect to Kafka running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker)

Comment: What do you mean by the values can be the same? They are not the same e.g. `2.7 != 2.7-IV1`

Comment: I am saying that Confluent Platform does not differ from "Apache Kafka", as it is _**included**_. The values _can be the same_, regardless of what the docs might say. Confluent docs team isn't the exact same as Apache Kafka team, though, they may have some staff overlap. Look [at 2.7 Kafka docs for `2.7-IV1, 2.7-IV2`](https://kafka.apache.org/27/documentation.html#brokerconfigs_inter.broker.protocol.version)

Comment: Ok, both sites sites list the valid values e.g. as 2.7-IV0, 2.7-IV1, 2.7-IV2 while they say in the upgrade guide to use 2.7 (which is not listed as a valid value, according to the doc).

Comment: I believe `IV` refers to patch releases. So, if you are upgrading to `2.7.0`, then `IV0`, for example