# Access "bitnami/kafka" docker container from everywhere

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, bitnami-kafka

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=broker,controller
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT:/:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@:9093
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
```

I can connect to it from other containers brought up by *docker-compose* using `kafka:9092`. From localhost, I can also connect using telnet: `telnet localhost 9092` (any dummy string throws an exception in kafka, but the connection is there).

When I do try to connect from a kafka consumer running on localhost using `localhost:9092`, I am getting `java.net.UnknownHostException: 1ffc30995c50: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`.
`1ffc30995c50` being the container id (and the hostname) of my kafka container.

As far as I understand `KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` is responsible for telling clients where to find the broker. In this case, it would have to return two different values ("kafka" to connect within the docker environment and "localhost" if outside) based on where the client connects from. Is that possible?

I hope that's clear and someone knows how to solve this. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to Kafka running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker)

Answer (score 7):

I think I worked it out (using the try and error approach^^)

```
version: "3"
services:
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9094:9094'

    environment:
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=broker,controller
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@:9093
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
```

Connect from within the docker network: `kafka:9092`
Connect from outside (localhost): `localhost:9094`

Comment: Stopping by to say thanks.

Comment: stopping by to say thanks as well :-)