# Can't connect to Kafka broker using spring.kafka.boostrap-servers

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am starting a Kafka broker using docker compose.

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
  
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

As a sanity check, I connected to it using Offset Explorer.

[image: offset explorer]

However, it doesn't work in Spring Boot when specifying `spring.kafka.boostrap-servers=localhost:29092` in application.properties.

```
2023-03-24T21:45:31.129-04:00  INFO 15008 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: 
        bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 2147483647
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
        sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
        sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS

2023-03-24T21:45:31.499-04:00  INFO 15008 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.3.2
2023-03-24T21:45:31.502-04:00  INFO 15008 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: b66af662e61082cb
2023-03-24T21:45:31.503-04:00  INFO 15008 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1679708731495
2023-03-24T21:45:31.566-04:00  INFO 15008 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-03-24T21:45:31.575-04:00  WARN 15008 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-03-24T21:45:31.698-04:00  INFO 15008 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-03-24T21:45:31.698-04:00  WARN 15008 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-03-24T21:45:31.917-04:00  INFO 15008 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-03-24T21:45:31.918-04:00  WARN 15008 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-03-24T21:45:32.243-04:00  INFO 15008 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-03-24T21:45:32.243-04:00  WARN 15008 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I had to specify that the zookeeper port is 22181 instead of 2181 to establish the connection, but I am not sure if it is important for Spring Boot since in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/) they mainly specify `props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");`.

[full code](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/microservices-quiz-app/tree/388ab3b7ea1a6e2d5b2b2c39bd76aa2106dbe069/scores)

Edit:
To keep it simple, the Spring Boot application wasn't running in a container.

Comment: You have a mistake in the name of the spring configuration parameter. Try `bootstrap` instead of `boostrap`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to Kafka running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker)

Comment: Is your Spring app also running in a container? If so, localhost refers itself not Kafka

Comment: @AlexanderBobryakov Oh you are right, my mistake. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simply a [typo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75839343/cant-connect-to-kafka-broker-using-spring-kafka-boostrap-servers?noredirect=1#comment133780341_75839343). Because of the typo, the default port was used `bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]`. I changed it to `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:29092` and it works now.

```
2023-03-25T16:30:03.911-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : 2023-03-25T16:30:03.911-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: 
        bootstrap.servers = [localhost:29092]
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 2147483647
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
        sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
        sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS

2023-03-25T16:30:04.615-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.3.2
2023-03-25T16:30:04.619-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: b66af662e61082cb
2023-03-25T16:30:04.621-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1679776204610
2023-03-25T16:30:09.220-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered
2023-03-25T16:30:09.236-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics scheduler closed
2023-03-25T16:30:09.236-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2023-03-25T16:30:09.238-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics reporters closed
2023-03-25T16:30:09.283-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-25T16:30:09.300-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [           main] c.m.scores.ScoresApplication             : Started ScoresApplication in 11.365 seconds (process running for 12.247)values: 
        bootstrap.servers = [localhost:29092]
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 2147483647
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
        sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
        sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS

2023-03-25T16:30:04.615-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.3.2
2023-03-25T16:30:04.619-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: b66af662e61082cb
2023-03-25T16:30:04.621-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1679776204610
2023-03-25T16:30:09.220-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered
2023-03-25T16:30:09.236-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics scheduler closed
2023-03-25T16:30:09.236-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2023-03-25T16:30:09.238-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [| adminclient-1] o.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics    : Metrics reporters closed
2023-03-25T16:30:09.283-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-25T16:30:09.300-04:00  INFO 11840 --- [           main] c.m.scores.ScoresApplication             : Started ScoresApplication in 11.365 seconds (process running for 12.247)
```