# Apache Kafka not able to set up broker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

On my standalone windows local machine i have apache kafka (2.11-2.0.0) along with my multi microservice app (spring java and python). For more than a year kafka ran fine. I never changed the settings nor touched it.

In the last week or so I noticed I was getting kafka issues in my app's logs

In python:

> No broker metadata found in MetadataResponse -- ignoring.

In spring java:

> Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3:
> {abc.process.file.request=LEADER_NOT_AVAVAILABLE}

both errors were just spamming in the logs. Initially I thought this was app issue and I tried everything I could including wiping out the code and rebuilding from scratch only to get the same error

Only after a long time of researching I found a workaround to modify kafka's server properties with:

```
port = 9092
advertised.host.name = localhost
```

App now working as normal but my question is why would I have to change server settings when it ran fine for a year plus.

The only thing I can think of is that for the last week I've (unsuccessfully) tried using WSL2 to install docker which included playing around with network config but i don't see how that would impact a localhost run, I'm not connecting to anything outside my PC

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you are using Docker... Are you not using a consistent Docker image tag? Therefore defaults to `:latest`? And therefore will pull the most recent Kafka version, where `port` and `advertised.host.name` have both been deprecated properties (and may now be removed)? (You should have been using `listeners` setting all along).

Or, have you not mounted persistent storage to that container, or otherwise mounted a folder like `/tmp` that may have been cleared.

WSL2 has had some upgrades over the last year, or so, therefore may have reset some state itself, including Docker images.

---

The above aren't really Kafka problems, but rather Docker best practices for having consistent, deterministic environments.

> playing around with network config

See [Connect to Kafka running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker) ; You should use Docker for Windows, and enable Docker Integration in the GUI, rather than `apt install docker`, manually , for example.