# dockerized Kafka service stuck at producer.send

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-python

I am very new to docker and Kafka, and have a simple kafka python publisher shown below

The following are in my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install --user pip==23.0.1 && pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

ENV ENVIRONMENT=production
CMD ["python3", "src/producer.py"]
```

as well as my yaml file for compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181

  publisher:
    container_name: publisher
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
```

in `producer.py` I have:.

```
import json 
from kafka import KafkaProducer,
sleep(10)

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092'], api_version=(0, 10))
json_path = "/data"
with open(json_path, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print('Ready to publish')
    for record in data:
        producer.send(topic, json.dumps(record).encode('utf-8'))
        print('Published message !!!')

producer.flush()
```

I first execute:

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

and then:

sudo docker run publisher

when I ctrl+c, I see the trackback printed, and only the line for `print('Ready to publish')` rather than 'print('Published message !!!')'

Howeve, when I simply do

```
   python3 src/producer.py
```

it prints both and publishes the messages without being stuck at the "send" method.

I have looked at a few other threads such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker), but none really helped finding the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You have no JSON files at `/data` mounted, or otherwise copied into the Dockerfile (everything is at `/app`. So, there's no files to read and produce. Plus, `open()` works on files, not directory paths

Secondly, you need to remove `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` and replace with `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092`, otherwise python app is stalling trying to connect to ***itself*** on port 9092, as the linked post and referenced blog indicates

> when I simply do...

As the code has been written, that shouldn't work.  `kafka` is an Unknown Host unless you've manually edited your `/etc/hosts` file... Which you shouldn't

Comment: the json file is found, I checked with a print to see if it has become available. I tried removing KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME and replaced it with what you suggestion, but is still not working.

Comment: with the change when I execute "sudo docker ps", I don't see kafka running

Comment: I haven't made any change in the /etc/hosts (it is an empty file)

Comment: 1) How did you get files into /data? You seem to be missing that from your question, as I don't think json files come with the Python container 2) You need to use `docker ps -a` to see crashed containers... If it's crashed, you need to look at its logs (or remove `-d` from your compose up command). Obviously Kafka code won't work if the broker is down (and you want `docker compose` without a hyphen)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Kafka procucer isn't able to reach the Kafka broker in the Docker network.

Since you've got the Kafka service in your docker-compose, that will act as the hostname within the Docker network.

So it should just be a case of updating the `bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092']` in your `producer.py` with an environmental variable, so it can be used both within the Docker netowork, and when the script is run outside Docker (w `python3 src/producer.py`).

```py
# Get env var
kafka_bootstrap_servers = os.environ.get("KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "localhost:9092")

# Use in producer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_bootstrap_servers, api_version=(0, 10))
```

Then, under `publisher` in your `docker-compose.yml` add:

```yaml
environment:
   KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
```

Then, when running within the Docker network is will use the environmental variable (`KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS`), but when running directly it will use the default value (`localhost:9092`)

Comment: it still has the same problem:/

Comment: eventhough I have set that KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS like you mentioned, the code doesn't find it