# No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm running a microservices project.  I have a `registration-service` microservice that is showing the following error:

```
2023-04-22 16:20:54.758 ERROR 12124 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:937) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
    at com.microservices.registration.RegistrationApplication.main(RegistrationApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:823) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:664) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createRawConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:483) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:451) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:427) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:394) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:371) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:852) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:381) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:531) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:226) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:531) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:383) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:328) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:89) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:730) ~[kafka-clients-3.1.2.jar:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've searched other SO posts and consulted other tools and can't get an answer to this problem. I have a local Zookeeper and Kafka (version 2.12-3.3.1) running on my local machine on port 9092.  I have set the spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers for localhost:9092 as well.  I have also tried changing it to localhost:9094 to see if I get something different.  I get the same error regardless.

Here are the pertinent files:

***KafkaConfig.java inside the `registration-service`:***

```
package com.microservices.registration.config;

import com.microservices.registration.model.RegistrationUser;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.*;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.StringJsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, RegistrationUser> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, RegistrationUser> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "registrationGroup");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(RegistrationUser.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, RegistrationUser> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, RegistrationUser> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, RegistrationUser> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Override //override this method to set the name of the database
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "registration";
    }



}
```

***application.yml for `registration-service`***

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: registration-service
  profiles:
    active: default
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:http://localhost:8071/
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
```

***POM for `registration-service`***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.microservices</groupId>
        <artifactId>microservices</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>registration-service</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.17.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.17.6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

***master POM dependencies***

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring.cloud.version>2021.0.6</spring.cloud.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.7.10</spring.boot.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.17.6</testcontainers.version>
        <spring.cloud.netflix.version>3.0.4</spring.cloud.netflix.version>
    </properties>
```

***registration-service.properties (in `configserver`)***

```
spring.application.name=registration-service
spring.kafka.topic.name=registrationUser
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=registrationUser
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/registration
spring.data.mongodb.database=registration
logging.level.root=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator=DEBUG
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration
# Configuration Server
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8071
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
```

Comment: spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers is set to kafka:9092 (what is kafka ?) in your configserver, did you configserver overide spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers in application.yml ?

Comment: Don't you think your `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092` overrides that from an `application.yml`?

Comment: The error is saying the address you've provided cannot be resolved. You need to show us that Kafka is actually running on ports `9092` or `9094` (you didn't say you modified Kafka properties, so don't know why you tried this). Also, `kafka:9092` is not the same as `localhost:9092`, so why are you trying to use some other hostname here? If you are using Docker, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker

Comment: I'm leaving this post up so it may help someone else, because I couldn't find the answer to this question on my own.  Basically, when you're inside a container, you need to address another container in the same network using the container's name or IP address and not use the term `localhost:<port>`.  Thanks for the learning experience.

Comment: You should add an answer; you should be able to "accept" it (click the check/tick mark) after a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

When running inside containers, you need to address another container in the same network using the container's service name or IP Address and not `localhost:<port>.`