# Spark Structured Streaming with Kafka client 3.4.0 Does not find topics, where it had worked with spark 2.2 and Kafka client 0.10.2.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am upgrading from spark 2.2 to 3.4.0 and my application also uses kafka stream as well, and with spark-3.4.0 I had to update kafka-client along with. I read somewhere that kafka-3.4.0 does not need depend on ZooKeeper and hence I had to update my code to create topic as follows

```
 import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.{AdminClientConfig, NewTopic, Admin}
    val properties = new Properties
    properties.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9094")
    val admin = Admin.create(properties)
    if (!admin.listTopics().names().get().contains(topicName)) {
      val newTopic = new NewTopic(topicName, 1, 1.toShort)
      val result = admin.createTopics(Collections.singleton(newTopic))
      val future = result.values.get(topicName)
      future.get()
    }
```

This successfully creates topic but When same broker are accessed for reading stream from topic I get exception,

```
val kafkaStream = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9094")
  .option("kafka.max.partition.fetch.bytes", settings.kafka.maxRequestSize)
  .option("startingOffsets", settings.kafka.startingOffsets)
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", settings.kafka.maxOffsetsPerTrigger.getOrElse(1000000L))
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .option("subscribe", topicName)
  .load()
```

Exception looks like

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy.retrieveAllPartitions(ConsumerStrategy.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.ConsumerStrategy.retrieveAllPartitions$(ConsumerStrategy.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.retrieveAllPartitions(ConsumerStrategy.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.assignedTopicPartitions(ConsumerStrategy.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderAdmin.$anonfun$partitionsAssignedToAdmin$1(KafkaOffsetReaderAdmin.scala:499)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderAdmin.withRetries(KafkaOffsetReaderAdmin.scala:518)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderAdmin.partitionsAssignedToAdmin(KafkaOffsetReaderAdmin.scala:498)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderAdmin.fetchLatestOffsets(KafkaOffsetReaderAdmin.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.$anonfun$getOrCreateInitialPartitionOffsets$1(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.getOrCreateInitialPartitionOffsets(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.initialOffset(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$getStartOffset$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:455)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.getStartOffset(MicroBatchExecution.scala:455)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$4(MicroBatchExecution.scala:489)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:488)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:932)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:477)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:12)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.withProgressLocked(MicroBatchExecution.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.constructNextBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:266)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:306)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:207)
```

Appreciate any help in this regards. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `kafka-clients:2.2` didn't depend on Zookeeper either... You shouldn't upgrade `kafka-clients` outside of `spark-sql-kafka-0-10` without good reason. But why are you using port 9094? Does this require some authentication settings, perhaps? Or what is `settings.kafka.brokers`?

Comment: port 9094 is kafka broker running out side docker container, settings.kafka.brokers is configurable value for kafka broker as localhost:9094

Comment: having kafka topic already created could get rid of this error but if kafka topic does not exists will get still same error

Comment: You mentioned Docker. Did you configure the broker correctly? Is your Spark code also running in a container? If so, then localhost will never connect. Otherwise, I still don't know why you'd need to change Kafka default port... And your error has nothing to do with the AdminClient. It's the consumer that's failing, which means it's your `settings.kafka.broker` value that you've not shared, which seems to be incorrect

Comment: @OneCricketeer spark code is running from intellij and kafka is running inside docker to connect kafka port is mapped with localhost so if I keep kafka topic pre-created, my code works well but if I delete kafka topics and try to run above code does not work. I need to create topic manually which was not the case with spark 2.2

Comment: Please show your docker compose file / run commands for Kafka. A simple port mapping [will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51634499/2308683)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set this option

```
spark.sql.streaming.kafka.useDeprecatedOffsetFetching = true
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#offset-fetching