# Kafka running in container - cannot connect from another container

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I've tried to follow the advice of some other excellent posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker/51634499#51634499) and others, but still running into problems.

I have two docker compose networks, one running kafka/zookeeper and another running a python application which includes a kafka producer, so needs to write to the container running kafka. I've created a network `kafka_logging_network` which both containers are a part of. I've double checked the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` variable many times but cant see what I'm missing.

The below shows the two `docker-compose.yml` files, followed by the `Dockerfile` and `main.py` for the application. `main.py` should run without error but in reality it cannot find any kafka brokers at the given `KAFKA_HOST` and `KAFKA_PORT`, raising `kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable`. Where have I gone wrong?

### kafka/docker-compose.yml (for kafka/zookeeper)

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  zoo1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.2
    hostname: zoo1
    container_name: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888
    networks:
      - logging_network

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.3.1
    hostname: kafka1
    container_name: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
    restart: always
    networks:
      - logging_network

networks:
  logging_network:
    driver: bridge
```

### app_folder/docker-compose.yml (for python application)

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  pyapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: pyapp
    networks:
      - kafka_logging_network
    environment:
      KAFKA_HOST: kafka1
      KAFKA_PORT: 29092
      KAFKA_TOPIC: logs-topic

networks:
  kafka_logging_network:
    external: true
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.7
COPY . .
RUN pip install kafka_python==2.0.2
ENTRYPOINT python main.py
```

### main.py

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import os

host = os.environ['KAFKA_HOST']
port = os.environ['KAFKA_PORT']

kp = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=f'{host}:{port}')
print('success')
```

Comment: I think the port of kafka you are trying to connect in docker-compose is wrong. Can you please double check it?

Comment: It might be because you added the port `29092` in your advertised listeners, but you're trying to use `19092` in your application.

Comment: My bad - error in question. I actually have 29092 in advertised listeners and 29092 in application.

Comment: No @GuillaumeBarré - they are separate compose commands. So `docker-compose up` is run twice - once for Kafka, once for the python app.

Comment: Note: You should use Bootstrap server string as one app environment variable. In production, you shouldn't define just one host and port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have configured kafka and the client application is fine.

Actually you have just a problem with how your kafka is trying to access Zookeeper

```
environment:
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
```

You don't have a service named 'zookeeper' but 'zoo1'

Replace your configuration by :

```
environment:
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zoo1:2181'
```