# After setting up Kafka with Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

After setting up Kafka with Docker, I created a topic called 'my-topic' and tried to send and receive messages using a producer and consumer. However, I am unable to receive any messages. What could be the possible issue in this case? Topic retrieval is working fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6tWi.png)

The message was sent as shown in the picture. But no message came.

I tried creating a consumer group, but I get a timeout exception.

Docker network is tied to ZooKeeper and Kafka.

Comment: Please show your docker run command or compose file, as text, not an image

Answer (score 0):

> no message came

Kafka Producers will batch data into one large request, and will not send each time you hit Enter key on console producer. You'll need to close the stream using <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> before the buffer is flushed.

Also, consumers default to read from the **end** of any topic (where there is no data until you produce data after starting the consumer) unless you use `--from-beginning`.

I see you're also using `kafka:9092`, which is not necessary when using `docker exec`; you can use `localhost`, as you did when listing the topics, but the port depends on other variables. [Connect to Kafka running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker)