# How to connect application to kafka pod in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I have k8s cluster with core-pod(this is my spring-boot application) and kafka pod.
There are services for connections to this services, but, when start application pod - there is connectivety issue. I tries to connect this containers in just simple docker and it was success

So, my application yml and pod yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
logging:
  level:
    nuclear.bot.core: TRACE
notification:
  level: INFO
spring:
  kafka:
    template:
      default-topic: PARSER.EVENT
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: kafka-service:9092
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: nuclear.bot.core.config.MessageAdapter
      group-id: core
    properties:
      key-class: java.lang.String
      value-class: nuclear.bot.core.dto.AgentMessage
```

so application try to connect to kafka-service on port 9092

and my app pod like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: core
  labels:
    app: core
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: core-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      name: core-pod
      labels:
        app: core-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nuclear-bot-core
          image: vladi15151/nuclear-bot-core:0.9.7
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
```

So, kafka which I trying to connect like this (pod and service together)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka-service
  name: kafka-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: kafka-broker
  ports:
    - name: kafka-port
      port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
      nodePort: 30126
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka-broker
  name: kafka-broker
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-broker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka-broker
    spec:
      hostname: kafka-broker
      containers:
        - image: bitnami/kafka
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: kafka-broker
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9092
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: "zookeeper-service:2181"
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
            - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
            # Creates a topic with one partition and one replica.
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE
              value: "true"
            - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
              value: "PARSEREVENT:1:1"
            - name: MY_POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER
              value: "yes"
```

Kafka successfully started on kluster, but application throw error message when try to start:

```
2023-06-09 21:53:26.193  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Bootstrap broker kafka-service:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-06-09 21:53:27.249  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-06-09 21:53:27.249  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Connection to node -1 (kafka-service/10.99.46.194:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-06-09 21:53:27.249  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Bootstrap broker kafka-service:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-06-09 21:53:28.205  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-06-09 21:53:28.205  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Connection to node -1 (kafka-service/10.99.46.194:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-06-09 21:53:28.205  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Bootstrap broker kafka-service:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-06-09 21:53:29.309  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-06-09 21:53:29.309  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Connection to node -1 (kafka-service/10.99.46.194:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-06-09 21:53:29.309  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Bootstrap broker kafka-service:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-06-09 21:53:30.113  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-06-09 21:53:30.113  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Connection to node -1 (kafka-service/10.99.46.194:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-06-09 21:53:30.113  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Bootstrap broker kafka-service:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-06-09 21:53:31.143  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-06-09 21:53:31.143  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Connection to node -1 (kafka-service/10.99.46.194:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-06-09 21:53:31.143  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-core-1, groupId=core] Bootstrap broker kafka-service:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

What can I try to use more?

Comment: Note: `KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS` does nothing with the bitnami container. Check the docs

Comment: And `KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT` isn't doing anything since you have no Zookeeper service and bitnami container is using Kraft mode by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made the broker only allow for connection from itself, not external connections. You need to modify the two listener env variables.  [Connect to Kafka running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker)

Then, it would be better if you used [fully qualified address](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) `kafka-service.svc.cluster.local:9092`.

If you [use Strimzi](https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/17/accessing-kafka-part-1/), you'd not have this issue.