# How to connect docker-compose kafka from localhost?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafkajs

I have troubles with connection to kafka from localhost. I'm using kafka with KRaft without zookeper.

```
services:
  kafka_auth:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.2.1
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 2
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka_auth:9092,CONTROLLER://kafka_auth:9093,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka_auth:9092,EXTERNAL://127.0.0.1:9094
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@kafka_mqtt:9093,2@kafka_auth:9093,3@kafka_server:9093'
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
    volumes:
      - ./run_workaround.sh:/tmp/run_workaround.sh
    command: "bash -c '/tmp/run_workaround.sh && /etc/confluent/docker/run'"
    depends_on:
      - kafka_mqtt
    ports:
      - "9094:9094"

  api:
    image: node:18
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: sh -c "yarn install && yarn start:debug"
    depends_on:
      - kafka_mqtt
```

When I connect from api service it's connect without any errors, but when I try to connect outside of docker using same code on port 9094 I get an error:

```
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-08-06T01:16:06.815Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[BrokerPool] Closed connection","retryCount":27,"retryTime":10000}
```

run_workaround.sh

```
sed -i '/KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT/d' /etc/confluent/docker/configure
sed -i 's/cub zk-ready/echo ignore zk-ready/' /etc/confluent/docker/ensure
echo "kafka-storage format --ignore-formatted -t CLUSTER_ID -c /etc/kafka/kafka.properties" >> /etc/confluent/docker/ensure
```

nodejs

```
import {
  Kafka,
  Consumer,
} from 'kafkajs';
const kafka = new Kafka({
    clientId: 'clientId',
    brokers: process.env.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS.split(','),
    requestTimeout: 3600000,
    retry: {
      maxRetryTime: 10000,
      initialRetryTime: 10000,
      retries: 999999999,
    },
});

const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: 'groupId' });
consumer.connect().then(async () => {
  // here I also check all topics and create them if they don't exist
  await consumer.subscribe({ topics: ['topic1'] });
  await consumer.run({
    eachMessage: async ({ topic, message }) => {
      if (!message?.value) {
        return;
      }
      switch (topic) {
        case 'topic1':
          method(message.value.toString());
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    },
  });
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure Kafka is starting okay? KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS has 3 entries, but you've only shown one 2) How does your code run if `process.env.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` is undefined? And you need to use port 9092 between the two containers. Please show your command that you use outside of Docker to connect

Comment: 1) Yes, I can connect to it from app services and it works fine.I omitted this code. it does not apply to the problem, but the rest of the kafka_mqtt and kafka_server services are identical.
2) inside of api KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS='kafka_mqtt:9092', then I run it outside of Docker KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="127.0.0.1:9094"
I use the same code when I run it inside and outside of container.

Comment: `kafka_mqtt` is not the correct DNS name. Did you mean `kafka_auth`? (Also, Kafka is not using MQTT, and you have no "auth" enabled, so these names don't make sense to me) And it does apply to the problem if you use the incorrect address. Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker

Comment: sorry for typo. sure it's kafka_auth in my code. Thank you, I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding all Kafka services to the same network and an extra host host.docker.internal also I had an error in environment variables.

```
services:
  kafka_auth:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.2.1
    container_name: kafka_auth
    hostname: kafka_auth
    restart: always
    environment:
      # ...
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_LOCALHOST:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'LISTENER_LOCALHOST://kafka_auth:9192,LISTENER_DOCKER://kafka_auth:9194'
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'CONTROLLER://kafka_auth:9093,LISTENER_LOCALHOST://kafka_auth:9192,LISTENER_DOCKER://kafka_auth:9194'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'LISTENER_LOCALHOST'
    networks:
      - kafka_net
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
 networks:
  kafka_net:
    name: kafka_net
```