# Can't send message to kafka in doker container - wurstmeister/kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, dockerfile

I have a problem with sending messages to kafka broker that is in docker container - wurstmeister/kafka.

I tried to send message from producer on localhost using (to address localhost:9093) PLAINTEXT or (to address localhost:9092) SSL but it failed. For SSL i get handshake error on kafka container. For PLAINTEXT producer gets timeout on localhost - nothing happens in kafka container.

I'm using it with zookeeper that is also in docker container.

docker compose

```
version: '3'

services:
    zookeeper:
        image: local_zookeeper
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_zookeeper
        container_name: zookeeper
        volumes: 
            - zookeeperVolume:/etc/zookeeper/secrets
            - zookeeperVolume:/var/lib/zookeeper
            - zookeeperVolume:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13
            - zookeeperVolume:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
            - zookeeperVolume:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
        ports:
            - "2181:2181"
            
    kafka:
        image: local_kafka
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_kafka
        container_name: kafka    
        volumes: 
            - kafkaVolume:/etc/kafka/secrets
            - kafkaVolume:/kafka

        depends_on:
        - zookeeper
        ports:
        - "9092:29092"
        - "9093:29093"
          
volumes:
    kafkaVolume:
    zookeeperVolume:
```

zookeeper dockerfile

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest

ENV ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT 2181
ENV ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME 2000
```

kafka dockerfile  ( its created via docker compose so I used container name as adress)

```
FROM wurstmeister/kafka

ENV KAFKA_BROKER_ID 1
ENV KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS INTERNAL_PLAIN://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL_PLAIN://localhost:29092, INTERNAL_SSL://kafka:9093,EXTERNAL_SSL://localhost:29093
ENV KAFKA_LISTENERS EXTERNAL_PLAIN://:29092,INTERNAL_PLAIN://:9092,EXTERNAL_SSL://:29093,INTERNAL_SSL://:9093
ENV KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP INTERNAL_SSL:SSL,EXTERNAL_SSL:SSL,INTERNAL_PLAIN:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_PLAIN:PLAINTEXT
ENV KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME INTERNAL_PLAIN
ENV KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT zookeeper:2181
ENV KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR 1
ENV KAFKA_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES 1195725856
ENV KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS "-Xmx12g -Xms1g"
ENV KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE true
ENV KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH 'required'
ENV KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION etc/kafka/secrets/certs/keystore.jks
ENV KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD pass
ENV KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD pass
ENV KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION etc/kafka/secrets/certs/truststore.jks
ENV KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD pass
ENV KAFKA_SSL_ENABLED_PROTOCOLS TLSv1.2
ENV KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS DUMMY-TOPIC:1:1
ENV KAFKA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS 5000

COPY ["kafka/keystore.jks", "etc/kafka/secrets/certs/keystore.jks"]
COPY ["kafka/truststore.jks", "etc/kafka/secrets/certs/truststore.jks"]
```

I created container with mapping ports - for zookeeper "2181:2181" and for kafka "9092:29092", "9093:29093"

Comment: Is there a specific need for the wurstmeister container over confluent? Also, why not use a compose file where you can **mount** your JKS files rather than copy and also apply all those env vars? You should not put those listeners in your Dockerfile since there is no guarantee your container will have `kafka` as a hostname (causing the listener to be incorrect, and zookeeper container is not guaranteed to be named `zookeeper`, meaning `KAFKA_ZOOKEEEPER_CONNECT` is incorrect as well, therefore kafka server would crash)... That being said, please add the kafka server logs to your post

Comment: sorry, I didn't add docker compose that I created for those dockerfiles - i updated post with docker compose.  Sure it could be confluent.

Comment: I'm not sure about SSL specifically, but PLAINTEXT should work. You have defined `localhost:29092` in your listeners, and not forwarded that in your compose file, which is why that does not work. Similarly, `29093`... Try to review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker

Comment: i rebuild solution and everything now its in docker compose , but ssl still dont work -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77171853/problem-with-connecting-to-docker-kafka-container-ssl-ssl-handshake-failed