# Problem with connecting to docker kafka container (confluent kafka) via ssl , Error - SSL handshake failed Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

Tags: java, docker, ssl, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have problem with connecting from local host machine to kafka broker in container.

Plaintext listener only works when KAFKA_LISTENERS for EXTERNAL_PLAIN is set to  EXTERNAL_PLAIN://:9092  ( EXTERNAL_PLAIN://localhost:9092 doesn't work)

But for below setup when I try to send message on ssl -> localhost:9093 using same keystores and passwords like in container setup I get  Error - SSL handshake failed  Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown.

Kafka spring config in application.properties:

```
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.request.size=6000000
#KAFKA GENERAL
spring.kafka.client-id=local_kafka_producer
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9093
auto.create.topics.enable=true
spring.kafka.producer.group-id=producer_local
spring.kafka.security.protocol=SSL
spring.kafka.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.trust-store-location=file:C:\\docker\\truststore.jks
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.trust-store-password=password
spring.kafka.ssl.key-password=password
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.key-store-location=file:C:\\docker\\keystore.jks
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.key-store-password=password
```

Producer config

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        final Map<String, Object> props = kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties();
        props.putAll(kafkaProperties.getProducer().buildProperties());
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaProducerTemplate(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory(kafkaProperties));
    }
}
```

and I'm using Autowired kafkaTemplate to send message.

My docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
        container_name: zookeeper
        hostname: zookeeper
        environment:
            ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        volumes: 
            - zookeeperVolume:/etc/zookeeper/secrets
            - zookeeperVolume:/var/lib/zookeeper
            - zookeeperVolume:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13
            - zookeeperVolume:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
            - zookeeperVolume:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
        ports:
            - 2181:2181
            
    kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
        container_name: kafka
        hostname: kafka
        environment:
            KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
            KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092, SSL://localhost:9093
            KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092, SSL://:9093 
            KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
            KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_SASL_ENABLED: false
            KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
            KAFKA_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES: 1195725856
            KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: "-Xmx12g -Xms1g"
            KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: true
            KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
            KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: ""
            KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: ACCOUNTS-CBC-CBA-BookingHVLPReq-POC:1:1
            KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: 'required'
            KAFKA_SSL_ENABLED_PROTOCOLS: TLSv1.2
            KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: keystore.jks
            KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: pass_for_truststore_keystore.txt
            KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: pass_for_truststore_keystore.txt
            KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: truststore.jks
            KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: pass_for_truststore_keystore.txt
            
        depends_on:
        - zookeeper        
        volumes: 
            - ./kafkaSsl:/etc/kafka/secrets
            - kafkaVolume:/var/lib/kafka/data
            - kafkaVolume:/kafka
        ports:
        - 9092:9092
        - 9093:9093
          
volumes:
    kafkaVolume:
    zookeeperVolume:
```

Comment: You'll need to share your process for creating your JKS files and your client code that's connecting, please

Comment: jks files are proper and I'm using them in local kafka broker and apps hosted on local tomcat or weblogic ( more then few months :) ). I updated my post with producer config.

Comment: I'm not sure those properties are correct. For example, group id isn't a producer config... In any case, when the producer starts, it logs all the properties that have been set, so are they all set as you expect?

Comment: So in kafkaTemplate -> producerFactory -> configs ->

values:
`
- bootstrap.servers= localhost:9093
- key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
- ssl.key.password=password
- ssl.truststore.password=password
- client.id=dummy
- ssl.protocol=TLS1.2
- ssl.keystore.location=C:\docker\keystore.jks
- security.protocol=SSL
- max.request.size=600000
- value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
- ssl.truststore.location=C:\docker\truststore.jks
- ssl.keystore.password=password
`
**Looks like all values are loaded correct.**

Comment: I meant in the ProducerConfig logs at runtime, not Spring values. Similarly for the broker. For example, `SSL_ENABLED_PROTOCOLS` is missing the `KAFKA_` prefix that's necessary for updating the broker config

Comment: **ssl log from kafka broker:**
ssl.cipher.suites = [], ssl.client.auth = required
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3], ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null, ssl.key.password = [hidden]
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509, ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null, ssl.keystore.location = /etc/kafka/secrets/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password = [hidden] , ssl.keystore.type = JKS

Comment: ssl.principal.mapping.rules = DEFAULT, ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
ssl.provider = null , ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX, ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = /etc/kafka/secrets/truststore.jks, ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
ssl.truststore.type = JKS

Comment: **producer logged config:**
 ssl.cipher.suites = null
 ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
 ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
 ssl.engine.factory.class = null
 ssl.key.password = [hidden]
 ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
 ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
 ssl.keystore.key = null
 ssl.keystore.location = C:\docker\keystore.jks
 ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]

Comment: ssl.keystore.type = JKS
 ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
 ssl.provider = null
 ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
 ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
 ssl.truststore.certificates = null
 ssl.truststore.location = C:\docker\truststore.jks
 ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
 ssl.truststore.type = JKS
 transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
 transactional.id = null
 value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

Comment: props are from logs when i started spring producer and when i started kafka broker.

Comment: I changed a little bit docker compose but still have handshake error and in logs there is a problem with zookeeper broker. 
**[SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1] Failed authentication with /192.168.144.1 (channelId=192.168.144.3:9093-192.168.144.1:55526-6) (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)**
 - @OneCricketeer
 it could be problem with connecting zookeeper with kafka broker ? I just want to use SSL only for kafka broker.

Comment: Zookeeper isn't required if you run the broker in Kraft mode. For the rest, I'm not sure. I'd recommend getting kafka-console-producer working first before moving into custom clients like spring

Comment: thanks for help :D digging into config with your suggestion helped me :) THANKS!!!

Comment: Feel free to post your working solution below as an answer