# Zookeeper Command [/usr/local/bin/dub path /var/lib/zookeeper/data writable] FAILED

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

everybody, I have a problem. I want to create through docker-compose two containers, zookeeper and kafka. I do it like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    volumes:
      - /srv/zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - /srv/zookeeper_log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT://192.168.100.9:9092"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - /srv/kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka/data
```

Doing docker-compose build and docker-compose up, I see errors in the console:

```
zookeeper_1         | ===> Running preflight checks ...
zookeeper_1         | ===> Check if /var/lib/zookeeper/data is writable ...
zookeeper_1         | Command [/usr/local/bin/dub path /var/lib/zookeeper/data writable] FAILED !
zookeeper_1 exited with code 1
kafka_1             | ===> Running preflight checks ...
kafka_1             | ===> Check if /var/lib/kafka/data is writable ...
```

With all that said, the directories **srv/kafka_data**, **srv/zookeeper_data** and **srv/zookeeper_log** exist. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my problem by changing the volume path to:

```
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    volumes:
      - zookeeper-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - zookeeper-log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://192.168.100.9:9092"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data
volumes:
  zookeeper-data:
  zookeeper-log:
  kafka-data:
```

Comment: Note: Don't use IP addresses. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker