# How to reach docker container built with docker compose on postman or browser?

Tags: macos, docker-compose

I have a springboot app on port 1993 backed with postgresql database on port 5432. Then I use docker compose up to build and run both images. The Postgres database is up and running. The springboot app is also up and running, because it creates a new topic in my docker Kafka cluster as expected. This mean that the docker container are able to communicate between each other inside docker using their container name. But I can neither reach the springboot app from postman with the container name nor with localhost or the container's IP address. From Postman I get

```
Error: socket hang up.
```

Even the GET methods to display a simple "Hello"  are not accessible from the browser. This my docker compose file.

```
`version: '3.1'
services:
  agcu_registration_db:
    container_name: agcu_registration_db
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=agcu_registration_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
        - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/agcu_data

  customer-registration:
    container_name: customer-registration_c
    image: customer-registration_i
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '1993:8080'
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    depends_on:
      - agcu_registration_db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://agcu_registration_db:5432/agcu_registration_db
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update`
```

**EDITED:**
I'm working on macOS Montery 12.1, with docker desktop 4.22 version for Mac, with postman 10.20 version and with an antivirus installed on the PC. Could this be a postman proxy issue ? If it is it, how to solve it on Mac ? If it is a docker networking issue, which network changes should be made in both docker and postman sides to make containers built with docker compose reachable from postman ? Even when I disable the antivirus I get the same result. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Postman isn't your problem. Port forwarding is... Why are you using `1993:8080`. instead of `8080:8080`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the reply. For you question I already have a sringboot microservice with port mapped as 8080:8080. Similarly I mapped all my springboot services 1993:8080; 1994:8080 1995:8080 and so on... to avoid port conflict. Is that a bad practice ?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Also I want to mention that I have kafka-ui running on port "9095:8080", because Kafka-ui 's default port is 8080

Comment: You can change ports. But you've not shown if you are using `localhost:1993` in Postman. Also, Postman isn't the problem. You can probably reproduce with `curl http://localhost:1993` as well. Or as mentioned in the comments below, how do we know the app actually remains running after creating a topic, and everything? Can you share `docker ps` after you see any HTTP errors?

Comment: @OneCricketeer when I console curl http://localhost:1993/users/admin I receive curl: (52) Empty reply from server. I tried localhost:1993, 127.0.0.1:1993 and 0.0.0.0:1993, all yield Error: socket hang up

Comment: @OneCricketeer but you are right about the app actually running on not, for I inspected the container and it says "2023-12-02 02:27:21 2023-12-02T10:27:21.663Z  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-registrationGroup-1, groupId=registrationGroup] Node -1 disconnected."

Comment: @OneCricketeer and this at the end : (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

Comment: Kafka isn't running on the spring container, so your bootstrap server is incorrect. That's unrelated to the original question. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker

Comment: @OneCricketeer , Ok I understand the fact that Kafka isn't running on the spring container and because of that my springboot endpoint calling Kafka Controller fails Ok ! Does it explain why the simple endpoint to display "Hello world" without any Kafka service behind also fails and says Error: socket hang up on Postman ? I start experiencing this only on my M1 MacBook Pro 2019. On my previous MacBook 2015, I was able to work with docker and postman together without issue. Does the failure of the Kafka Server also shuts down any client using it ?

Comment: @OneCricketeer For the Kafka part I head on to the link you shared and I find it new and with very helpful features. Thanks, I'm still on it.

Comment: _Does the failure of the Kafka Server also shuts down any client using it ?_ - That would depend on how your code handles exceptions during startup. The Docker Compose output tells you when containers exit

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Spring Boot application.properties or application.yml :

```
server.address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But after adding that to the application.properties, how should I then call the endpoints on postman or browser? localhost:1993/user/xxxx or 0.0.0.0:1993/user/xxxx or agcu_registration_c:1993/user/xxxx. Thank again.

Comment: According your configs use localhost

Comment: After setting server.address=0.0.0.0 I receive the same error message Error: socket hang up when calling the endpoints via localhost. When calling it via the container name agcu_registration_c which I mapped in the /etc/host to localhost I receive Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND agcu_registration_c. When I use 0.0.0.0:user/xxxx  I also get Error: socket hang up

Comment: I meant use localhost:1993/user/xxx, are you in windows ?

Comment: I'm on macbook with Montery 12.1 OS. Calling localhost:1993/user/xxx gives Error: socket hang up.

Comment: did you check if the port 1993 is not blocked in Firewall  ? And why did you change the port 8080 ?

Comment: How do you know the Spring app actually starts a server at all?