# How do I connect to a dockerized Kafka cluster from outside Docker?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, configuration

My organization has recently switched from an older version of Kafka, that relied on Zookeeper, to a more recent version that can act as its own broker. Unfortunately, in doing so, [they broke my workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/).

I have a small program intended to produce kafka messages to a specific topic. When I run a dockerized version of the program, it connects to kafka and functions as expected. When I try to run the program directly from my IDE, and connect to dockerized kafka cluster, I get a mysterious "Client has run out of available brokers to talk to: EOF" error.
[screenshot of the error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmbPO.png)

Since the program works when run in a container, I presume there is some configuration discrepancy at the root cause of my troubles. This setup *does not use Zookeeper*, and unfortunately, most of the literature I can find online is about how to make this work *with* Zookeeper, which is no longer relevant to our organization.

The compose file for the Kafka container:

```
# KAFKA
  kafka:
    <<: *logging
    image: bitnami/kafka:3.5.1
    labels:
      niche.type: "kafka"
    container_name: kafka
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      # Tell kafka that it's running in single-node mode
      KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID: 0
      KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES: controller,broker
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 0@kafka:9093
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      KAFKA_CFG_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_CFG_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    networks:
      - development
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: kafka3-data
        target: /bitnami/kafka
      - type: tmpfs
        target: /bitname/kafka/tmp
```

The compose block for the dockerized version of my program. It is mostly relying on the defaults

```
inventory:
    <<: [ *dns, *logging ]
    build:
      context: ./inventory
      dockerfile: ./cmd/inventory/Dockerfile
    image: ${USER:?USER}/inventory:latest
    container_name: inventory
    env_file:
      - urls.env
      - inventory/cmd/inventory/docker.env
    networks:
      - development
    ports:
      - 4096:4096
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_started
      kafka:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Which are defined as such:

```
KAFKA_BROKERS=kafka:9092
```

Running my program from within my IDE, I provide

```
"args": [
                "-kafka.brokers=localhost:29092"
]
```

I suspect the trouble is that I'm not hitting the Kafka container in the correct way -- 29092 is correct for the container, and if I target a different port, I get a "could not connect" error instead -- but I'm less sure about the listeners being `//localhost:29092`.

I thought this maybe should have been `docker.host.internal` (to specify incoming connections from the host machine on that port), but the Kafka image didn't seem to know how to interpret that.

Any pointers as to where I might be going wrong? This workflow was previously possible with Zookeeper, so I would expect it is just a configuration problem that is preventing this from working as intended. Running on Windows, for what it's worth.

Comment: You shouldn't have been Zookeeper as the connection string, anyway, but try to replace `EXTERNAL://localhost:29092` with `EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092`

Comment: To clarify, for `KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS` only. Otherwise, only local connections within the container are allowed to that port

Comment: @OneCricketeer That tweak resolves it for me. Post that as an answer and I will accept it. A brief explanation of what this is doing differently from `localhost` would be icing. Either way, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

```
KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://localhost:29092
```

---

`listeners` config (`KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS` on the Bitnami image) sets what bind address the server will listen to.

When set to `localhost`, it'll only accept internal (relative to the container) connections.

When set to `0.0.0.0`, it'll accept connections on all interfaces (such as from the host), and only **then** will Compose port forwarding work from the host to the container.

Additionally, `KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` must remain with `<protocol>://localhost:<port>` for the matching listener since that is the address returned to the clients running outside the container, assuming running on the same machine.

More details: [Connect to Kafka running in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker)