# Connection from external kafka client to kafka server fails

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am running kafka server using docker-compose with below configuration in node2.

```
---
version: '3'
services:
  zoo1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.2
    hostname: zoo1
    container_name: zoo1
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888
    ports:
     - "2181:2181"

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2
    hostname: kafka1
    container_name: kafka1
    ports:
    # To learn about configuring Kafka for access across networks see
    # https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
      - "29093:29093"
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://:29092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://:29093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9092,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://localhost:29092,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST://:29093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_DIFFERENT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

From node1, I am running a kafka client from a docker container, to create topic in kafka broker as shown below and it fails

```
~ $ ./goflow2 -transport=kafka -transport.kafka.brokers=10.10.26.207:9092 -transport.kafka.topic=flows -format=text
INFO[0000] starting GoFlow2
INFO[0000] starting collection                           blocking=false count=1 hostname= port=6343 queue_size=1000000 scheme=sflow workers=2
INFO[0000] starting collection                           blocking=false count=1 hostname= port=2055 queue_size=1000000 scheme=netflow workers=2
ERRO[0089] transport error                               error="kafka transport kafka: Failed to produce message to topic flows: dial tcp: lookup kafka1 on 10.10.13.22:53: server misbehaving"
ERRO[0104] transport error                               error="kafka transport kafka: Failed to produce message to topic flows: dial tcp: lookup kafka1 on 10.10.13.22:53: server misbehaving"
^CINFO[0108] closed receiver                               blocking=false count=1 hostname= port=6343 queue_size=1000000 scheme=sflow workers=2
INFO[0108] closed receiver                               blocking=false count=1 hostname= port=2055 queue_size=1000000 scheme=netflow workers=2
ERRO[0113] transport error                               error="kafka transport kafka: Failed to produce message to topic flows: dial tcp: lookup kafka1 on 10.10.13.22:53: server misbehaving"
ERRO[0133] transport error                               error="kafka transport kafka: Failed to produce message to topic flows: dial tcp: lookup kafka1 on 10.10.13.22:53: server misbehaving"
INFO[0153] closed transporter
INFO[0153] closed HTTP server                            http=":8080"
ERRO[0153] transport error                               error="kafka transport kafka: Failed to produce message to topic flows: dial tcp: lookup kafka1 on 10.10.13.22:53: server misbehaving"
```

From the same node i.e. node1 when I use kafkacat it seems to work fine as shown below

```
root@mm312:/home/ip# kafkacat -b 10.10.26.207:9092 -L -v
Metadata for all topics (from broker -1: 10.10.26.207:9092/bootstrap):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1 at kafka1:9092 (controller)
 52 topics:
  topic "_confluent-controlcenter-7-3-2-1-MonitoringTriggerStore-repartition" with 12 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 1, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 2, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 3, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 4, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 5, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 6, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 7, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 8, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 9, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 10, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 11, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
  topic "_confluent-controlcenter-7-3-2-1-metrics-trigger-measurement-rekey" with 12 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 1, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 2, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 3, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 4, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 5, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 6, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 7, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 8, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 9, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 10, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
    partition 11, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
  topic "flows" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
```

Any suggestions to troubleshoot this issue would be of great help.

Comment: "53: server misbehaving" often indicates that something is wrong with docker itself. Try restarting the docker daemon on both servers if possible, and see if the error persists.

Comment: @TeemuRisikko - I did try the same but no change in the behavior. Looks like DNS resolution for kafka1 is being tried and it is resulting in failure.

Comment: Your listeners are all the exact same, just different ports. You need to tell kafka to advertise the host  ip, not just do port forward. And, yes, docker DNS names won't work without an overlay network across hosts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker

Comment: @OneCricketeer - Thanks for the reply. I am just trying to understand why would I need overaly in my current case. Kafkacat on Node1 is able to connect with kafkaserver container in Node2 but kafkaclient container in Node1 is not able to. Are you saying metadata returned by kafkaserver is providing kafka1 instead of ipaddress ?

Comment: There's no DNS server between containers on other hosts, so the container names won't resolve without an overlay, but the host ip addresses would resolve, as shown by kafkacat