NoBrokersAvailable for a kafka, zookeeper, jupyter notebook and spark project
I'm trying to get infos about weather from openweather and sending them to kafka.
Currently everything is running and no error appear in docker but when running the code, I have a NoBrokersAvailable error.
Here is the code :
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import requests
import time
import json

API_KEY = 'my_api_key'
URL = f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=44.34&lon=10.99&appid={API_KEY}'
KAFKA_TOPIC = 'real-time-weather'

producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
    value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'),
)


def get_weather_data():
    response = requests.get(URL)
    return response.json()

while True:
    weather_data = get_weather_data()
    producer.send(KAFKA_TOPIC, value=weather_data)
    print(f'Send to Kafka : {weather_data}')
    time.sleep(60)

Here is the complete error :
NoBrokersAvailable                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 10
      7 URL = f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=44.34&lon=10.99&appid={API_KEY}'
      8 KAFKA_TOPIC = 'real-time-weather'
---> 10 producer = KafkaProducer(
     11     bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092',
     12     value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'),
     13 )
     16 def get_weather_data():
     17     response = requests.get(URL)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py:381, in KafkaProducer.__init__(self, **configs)
    378 reporters = [reporter() for reporter in self.config['metric_reporters']]
    379 self._metrics = Metrics(metric_config, reporters)
--> 381 client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, metric_group_prefix='producer',
    382                      wakeup_timeout_ms=self.config['max_block_ms'],
    383                      **self.config)
    385 # Get auto-discovered version from client if necessary
    386 if self.config['api_version'] is None:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py:244, in KafkaClient.__init__(self, **configs)
    242 if self.config['api_version'] is None:
    243     check_timeout = self.config['api_version_auto_timeout_ms'] / 1000
--> 244     self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py:900, in KafkaClient.check_version(self, node_id, timeout, strict)
    898 if try_node is None:
    899     self._lock.release()
--> 900     raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
    901 self._maybe_connect(try_node)
    902 conn = self._conns[try_node]

NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable

I'm quite new to the data world and it's my first docker project so I might not understand everything.

You've tagged docker, but not shared your docker config. Please [edit] your question and see https://stackoverflow.com/q/51630260/2308683
